# Why would let statement behave so much different from var?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I know `let` is to declare block scope local variables, but why doesn't it support redeclaration and hoisting like `var` does?

What's the design purpose of this limitation?

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    alert(a);       // undefined
    var a;
})();

(function(){
    'use strict';
    alert(a);       // error
    let a;
})();

(function(){
    'use strict';
    var a;
    var a;
    alert(a);       // undefined
})();

(function(){
    'use strict';
    let a;
    let a;          // error
    alert(a);
})();
```

Comment: @user2190986 but it is clear that `let` does not declare constants in JavaScript

Comment: @user2190986 `const` is used to declare constants.

Comment: `let` declarations **are** hoisted. But unlike `var` declarations the variable doesn't get initialized with `undefined` at the beginning of the block.

Comment: [In fact `let` declarations are hoisted](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31219420/1048572). Redeclarations are almost always a mistake (except in a REPL maybe), so they're an error now.

Answer (score 8):

The idea is to create a tool that's more unambiguous and more strict than the original `var`.

As a human, the following is valid JavaScript but nearly impossible to understand:

```
alert(a); // Where does a come from? Why does this not throw?
/* 1000 lines later, or even in an entirely different file */
var a;
```

Moreover, imagine code with 5 `var` declarations for the same variable on the same scope, some in `if` statements, some in `for`s. Which is the first? What value will end up being created?

The idea was to fix some of the **[bad parts of `var`](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)**.

Answer (score 1):

The same reason why any strict operator appears in any programming language - to limit the number of ways you can shoot yourself in the foot. Old-school Javascript is just chock full of those.

Note that you can use `let` for a block-local scope:

```
while (i < 5)
{
  let a = 42;

  i++;
}
```

Even though the loop runs a couple of times, `a` is always initialized properly.

Now, what would happen if you have another variable in the higher scope?

```
let a = 42;

while (i < 5)
{
  let a = 10;

  // What is the value of a here?
  i++;
}

// And here?
```

There's a certain level of ambiguity here - and ambiguity is a bad feature in a programming language. This isn't a problem with the non-block-scoped `var` - that one has tons of its own issues, and people misuse it all the time, but at least its obvious that `var` is *never* block-scoped. And even then - people do use it as if it *were* block-scoped.

The only way to fix this insanity is to make the language a bit stricter. Did this actually mean you lost any feature whatsoever? No. Variable shadowing was a bad idea with `var`, and it would still be a bad idea with `let` (and as my example shows, possibly worse).

This isn't unique to Javascript, not by a long shot. For example, in C#:

```
int i = 0;

int i = 42; // Compiler error: A local variable named 'i' is already defined in this scope
```

Why? Because you've *obviously* made a mistake. Perhaps you copied a piece of code from somewhere else, and didn't notice you already have another variable named `i` declared. Perhaps you forgot you're in the middle of another loop, that also uses `i` as a loop variable. There's no real legitimate use, and yet there's tons of failure modes - that's simply a terrible language feature. The simple compiler error prevents almost all of those failures from happening - and many of those failures can be very hard to find, especially if the "inner" block isn't used too often.