# JavaScript: define a constant inside try / catch with strict mode

Tags: javascript, try-catch, constants, ecmascript-6, strict

Today I run into a weird JS bug, working with `const` inside a try/catch block, and I'd like to better understand what is causing it.

Let's look at a code example, that is worth more than a thousand words:

```
try {
  const FOO = 'bar';
  console.log('inside:', FOO);
} catch (e) {}
console.log('outside:', FOO);
```

This will log:

```
inside: bar
outside: bar
```

If we switch to "strict mode" though:

```
'use strict';
try {
  const FOO = 'bar';
  console.log('inside:', FOO);
} catch (e) {}
console.log('outside:', FOO);
```

Now the same code produces an error:

```
ReferenceError: FOO is not defined
```

If we change `const` with `var` though:

```
'use strict';
try {
  var foo = 'bar';
  console.log('inside:', foo);
} catch (e) {}
console.log('outside:', foo);
```

Then it all works fine again, even in "strict mode":

```
inside: bar
outside: bar
```

Can anyone please help me understand why the `const` assignment is not working inside a try/catch block in "strict mode"?

Thanks!

Comment: Compare `const` with `let`, not `var`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`const`, as defined by ECMAScript 6, is a [block-level variable declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31219420/1048572). You get a `ReferenceError` because it's not in scope outside of the `try`.

However, `const` was introduced in [some engines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Firefox-specific_notes) long before ES6, as a immutable counterpart to `var`, with function-level scope behaviour (and without TDZ). If you're in sloppy mode (which you should not be), you might still experience this as part of your browser's legacy support.

Comment: I had no idea about legacy "`const`". MDN footnote: "In earlier versions of Firefox & Chrome and as of Safari 5.1.7 and Opera 12.00, if you define a variable with const, you can still change its value later."

Comment: @joews: yes, it was nothing better than an alias for `var` so that scripts written for FF (in the belief of a standard feature) would at least run without syntax errors in Safari and Opera as well, even if not guaranteeing unassignability.

Comment: "it will continue to work like this " - V8 in Chrome 48 (current Canary) applies block scope in either mode (tested in console/snippet; I can't find a reference). I guess this could change before release.

Comment: @joews: You're right, engines do shift towards ES5 compliance. It's just a slow process. Fixed wording in my answer.

Comment: For the morbidly curious, here is the relevant v8 revision history: https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2198

Answer (score 4):

Your JavaScript runtime has a partial implementation of [ES6 `const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).

`ReferenceError` is the expected behaviour for your first example, because [`const` is block scoped](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/es6-variable-declarations/) and you access `FOO` outside the defining `try` block.

The engine you are using supports the `const` syntax, but it only applies block scoping semantics in strict mode.

The current stable Chrome (46) does this. Chrome 48, however, applies block scope with or without strict mode.

`var` is not block scoped, so your last example works as expected.