# JavaScript weird behavior of try/catch when used with strict mode

Tags: javascript, exception, try-catch

I'm working on an existing function which is declared  using `use strict` mode. What I found weird is that when an exception is thrown, the `catch` block is not executed. I think that it's related to the `strict mode` line because when I get ride of it, it goes in `catch` block.

I always saw the main goal of using `try/catch` is to prevent code to be exited suddenly (without any control) when there's uncontrolled situation at runtime.

> A **catch** clause contains statements that specify what to do **if an**
>   **exception is thrown** in the try block.

When used with strict mode, it seems like it doesn't have no effect. Is there any explanation of that behavior ?

My code:

```js
function test(){
 "use strict"
 //...
 try {
  // var dt = new Date(2017, 10, 27, 15, 23, 9); /* works fine */
  var dt = new Date(2017, 10, 27, 15, 23, 09);
 } catch(e){
  console.log("inside catch");
 } finally {
    console.log("inside finally");
 }
 //...
}

test();
// output: Uncaught SyntaxError:
// Decimals with leading zeros are not allowed in strict mode.
```

**Remark**

Before asking the question, I looked at some questions at StackOverflow but I didn't found an explanation. For example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33457167/javascript-define-a-constant-inside-try-catch-with-strict-mode) is about the scope of `const` not the behavior of `try/catch` itself.

Comment: The use of octal is invalid syntax in strict mode, so the error is a Syntax Error. There is a previous discussion about this in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963045/syntax-errors-can-be-caught-in-javascript