# what is block scope function ECMAScript 6 compare with ECMAScript 5

Tags: javascript

What is block scope function in ECMAScript 6?

Can anyone help me understand the main difference in the block scope function compared to ECMAScript 5?

Comment: In case you were not asking about functions in block scopes, but block scopes in general, see [Are variables declared with let or const not hoisted in ES6?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31219420/1048572)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The new `let` and `const` in ES2015 (aka "ES6") have four major differences compared with the venerable `var`:

1. They have block scope
2. They aren't hoisted (well, they're *sort of* hoisted, but in a useful way)
3. Repeated declarations are errors
4. When used at global scope, they don't create properties of the global object (despite creating global variables; this is a new concept as of ES2015)

*(For what it's worth, this is covered in detail in Chapter 2 of my recent book [JavaScript: The New Toys](https://thenewtoys.dev), which covers ES2015-ES2020.)*

#### Block scope

`var` variables exist throughout the function they're declared in (or globally, if declared globally), they aren't confined to the block they're in. So this code is valid:

```js
function foo(flag) {
    a = 10;
    if (flag) {
        var a = 20;
    }
    return a;
}
console.log(foo(false)); // 10
console.log(foo(true));  // 20
```

`a` is defined regardless of whether `flag` is true and it exists outside the `if` block; all three `a`s above are the same variable.

That's not true of `let` (or `const`):

```js
function foo(flag) {
    if (flag) {
        let a = 10;
    }
    return a;           // ReferenceError: a is not defined
}
console.log(foo(true));
```

`a` only exists inside the block it's declared in. (For `for` statements, a declaration within the `()` of the `for` is handled very specially: a new variable is declared within the block for *each* loop iteration.) So outside the `if`, `a` doesn't exist.

`let` and `const` declarations can shadow declarations in an enclosing scope, e.g.:

```js
function foo() {
    let a = "outer";

    for (let a = 0; a < 3; ++a) {
        console.log(a);
    }
    console.log(a);
}
foo();
```

That outputs

```
0
1
2
outer
```

...because the `a` outside the `for` loop isn't the same `a` as the one *inside* the `for` loop.

#### Hoisting

This is valid code:

```
function foo() {
    a = 5;
    var a = a * 2;
    return a;
}
```

Bizarre-looking, but valid (it returns 10), because `var` is done before anything else is done in the function, so that's really:

```
function foo() {
    var a;             // <== Hoisted

    a = 5;
    a = a * 2;         // <== Left where it is
    return a;
}
```

That's not true of `let` or `const`:

```
function foo() {
    a = 5;            // <== ReferenceError: a is not defined
    let a = a * 2;
    return a;
}
```

You can't use the variable until its declaration. The declaration isn't "hoisted" (well, it's *partially* hoisted, keep reading).

Earlier I said

> 2. They aren't hoisted (well, they're *sort of* hoisted, but in a useful way)

"Sort of"? Yes. A `let` or `const` declaration shadows an identifier throughout the block in which it appears, even though it only actually takes effect where it occurs. Examples help:

```
function foo() {
    let a = "outer";

    for (let x = 0; x < 3; ++x) {
        console.log(a);            // ReferenceError: a is not defined
        let a = 27;
    }

}
```

Note that instead of getting `"outer"` in the console, we get an error. Why? Because the `let a` in the `for` block shadows the `a` outside the block even though we haven't gotten to it yet. The space between the beginning of the block and the `let` is called the "temporal dead zone" by the spec. Words aren't everybody's thing, so here's a diagram:

[image: TMZ]

#### Repeated declarations

This is valid code:

```
function foo() {
    var a;

    // ...many lines later...
    var a;
}
```

The second `var` is simply ignored.

That's not true of `let` (or `const`):

```
function foo() {
    let a;

    // ...many lines later...
    let a;                     // <== SyntaxError: Identifier 'a' has already been declared
}
```

#### Globals that aren't properties of the global object

JavaScript has the concept of a "global object" which holds various global things as properties. In loose mode, `this` at global scope refers to the global object, and on browsers there's a global that refers to the global object: `window`. (Some other environments provide a different global, such as `global` on NodeJS.)

Until ES2015, all global variables in JavaScript were properties of the global object. As of ES2015, that's still true of ones declared with `var`, but not ones declared with `let` or `const`. So this code using `var` at global scope, on a browser, displays 42:

```js
"use strict";
var a = 42; // Global variable called "a"
console.log(window.a); // Shows 42, because a is a property of the global object
```

But this code shows `undefined` for the properties, because `let` and `const` at global scope don't create properties on the global object:

```js
"use strict";
let a = 42; // Global variable called "a"
console.log(a); // 42 (of course)
console.log(window.a); // undefined, there is no "a" property on the global object
const q = "Life, the Universe, and Everything"; // Global constant
console.log(q); // "Life, the Universe, and Everything" (of course)
console.log(window.q); // undefined, there is no "q" property on the global object
```

---

Final note: Much of the above also holds true if you compare the new ES2015 `class` (which provides a new, cleaner syntax for creating constructor functions and the prototype objects associated with them) with function declarations (as opposed to function *expressions*):

- `class` declarations have block scope. In contrast, using a function declaration within a flow-control block is **invalid**. (It should be a syntax error; instead, different JavaScript engines handle it differently. Some relocate it outside the flow-control block, others act as though you'd used a function *expression* instead.)
- `class` declarations aren't hoisted; function declarations are.
- Using the same name with two `class` declarations in the same scope is a syntax error; with a function declaration, the second one wins, overwriting the first.
- `class` declarations at global scope don't create properties of the global object; function declarations do.

Just as a reminder, this is a function *declaration*:

```
function Foo() {
}
```

These are both function *expressions* (*anonymous* ones):

```
var Foo = function() {
};
doSomething(function() { /* ... */ });
```

These are both function *expressions* (*named* ones):

```
var Foo = function Foo() {
};
doSomething(function Foo() { /* ... */ });
```

Comment: This teaches me a lot about variable hoisting in ES6. But the question was around function scopes and block scoped functions in ES6.

Comment: @SunnyRGupta: I'm glad it was helpful for that. :-) Re the question: No, I don't think it was. And apparently the person posting the question didn't either, as they've accepted this answer. I don't think the word "function" in their question is meant literally. Read "mechanism" instead of "function."