# Immediately Invoked Function Expression and document ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In Javascript using jQuery i can add scope to the function using [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) and  pass the function jQuery, and name the parameter $

```
(function ( $ ) { 

    $.fn.greenify = function() {
        this.css( "color", "green" );
        return this;
    }; 

}( jQuery ));
```

Similarly, we write document ready function as below

```
$(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    // use $ variable here
});
```

Does that mean document ready function is already scoped?
Do i also need to pass the function jQuery, and name the parameter $ in document ready function? something like below

```
$(function ( $ ) {
    console.log( "ready!" ); 
    // use $ variable here   
 }( jQuery ));
```

Comment: Any time you have a `function() {}`, there is a scope associated with that method.  Once you get into ES6, using block scope `{}` with `let` and `const` (and maybe one more?) has a scope as well.  Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34564403/what-is-block-scope-function-ecmascript-6-compare-with-ecmascript-5#34564497

Comment: $ and jQuery are really window.$ and window.jQuery. So no need to additionaly pass jQuery as a parameter to IIFE unless you want to create a shadow local variable $ inside this IIFE scope with same value.

Comment: Also you don't have to pass $ to a doc ready, but you can.  `jQuery(function($){});`  This is helpful if the noConflict is active.

Answer (score 0):

The IIFE is invoked immediately, it won't wait for `document` to get ready. So:

```
(function($) {

    // here document is not necessarly ready

})(jQuery);
```

When you do `$(function() { ... });` you are not creating an IIFE, you are just passing a function (callback) to be executed when the `document` is ready.

If you want to do both, then use:

```
(function($) {

    $(function() {

        // here, document is really ready
        // $ available here too

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Or do it like this (using the fact that jQuery [passes itself as parameter to its ready callback](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3)):

```
jQuery(function($) {

    // here, document is really ready
    // and $ is obviously available (only here)

});
```

Comment: You said `When you do $(function() { ... }); you are not creating an IIFE, you are just passing a function (callback) to be executed when the document is ready`... So if i have 2 document ready functions on the same page. and both document ready functions are using same variable name but different value like `var num = 1111` and `var num = 9999` aren't these variables scoped to respective document ready function?

Comment: @LP13 I think you may be confusing **functions scopes** in general, with **functions scopes** used in IIFEs specially. Both are the same, because both are function scope. `function() { anything declared in here is only visible inside here }`. Anything declared inside the function's body is only visible inside that body, no matther how the function is used: whether it's used as an IIFE or as a callback to another function (like `$(...)`).