# async function or async => when exporting default?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, arrow-functions, es6-modules

```
export default async function () {

};
```

or

```
export default async () => {

};
```

Which one is preferred when exporting a default function and why?

Comment: If you're not going to name the function, probably the second one

Comment: Does the code that will be calling the function need to be able to `.call()`, `.apply()`, or `.bind()` it?

Comment: In the first example, there is no need for the final semi-colon.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The first one is generally preferred. It's a declaration, not an expression value, which has [subtle advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35225936/1048572). And it can easily be named if you want, which [is a good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15336347/1048572). Also, [arrow functions have a few disadvantages in certain situations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361380/1048572), so unless you absolutely need them to preserve a `this` value (etc.) you'd rather avoid them. Saving 5 characters to type is hardly worth it.

Comment: Exactly what I as wanting to hear! Thank you!