# difference between rfc and rfce in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am new in Reactjs and I want to know what is the difference between "react functional component"
and "react functional component export"?

Here is react functional component code

```
import React from 'react'
export default function Test() {
  return (
    <div>Test</div>
  )
}
```

Here is "react functional component export"

```
import React from 'react'
function Test() {
  return (
    <div>Test</div>
  )
}

export default Test
```

Comment: Both are same, just different way of writing

Comment: @Rajesh: And what about "rfcp" (react functional component with prop types) ?

Comment: That is a way to define what props a component will have and what would their types be.

Comment: Related: [exporting a declaration vs an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35223111/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

I want to add more context to your question: I suppose your question comes from the different snippets `rfc` and `rfce` of [ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets](https://github.com/dsznajder/vscode-react-javascript-snippets/blob/HEAD/docs/Snippets.md) extension in VScode.

Two both cases do the same thing. The differences are the syntax of `export`. It's not particular to **ReactJS** but about **JavaScript**.

- **1st case**: you use `export` directly before the declaration function line.
- **2nd case**: you declare a function first and later use `export` with the function's name at the bottom of your code.

I'm used to using 2nd case.

You can read more about `export` syntax variant + *named export* vs. `default` *export* in this [link](https://javascript.info/import-export#export-before-declarations)

Comment: The first (`export` declaration) is actually preferred since it exports the binding itself, and works better in circular dependencies due to hoisting.

Answer (score -1):

You mean the difference between **Functional Components** And **Class Components**?
The functions you have shared are the same, both are React Functional Component

**React Class Components:** is a class component requires you to extend from React Component and create a render function which returns a React element.

example:

```
import React from 'react'

export default class Test extends React.Component {
  render () {
    console.log(this.props)
    return <div>Test</div>
  }
}
```

**React Functional Components:** is just a plain JavaScript pure function that accepts props as an argument and returns a React element(JSX)

example:

```
import React from 'react'
export default function Test(props) {
  console.log(props)
  return (
    <div>Test</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: In which situation we should use "class component" and in which situation we should use "functional components" ?