# Typescript class: will class be hoisted when I use two classes?

Tags: javascript, typescript

## background

#### 1.class should be defined in advance

I know there is no error because class is defined in advance.

```ts
class Polygon {
  log() { console.log('i am polygon'); }
}
const p = new Polygon();  // no error as I had expected.
p.log();
```

#### 2.class is not hoisted

I also know the reason of this error. 
class is not hoisted, so this error is my expected result.

```ts
const b = new Bolygon();  // Uncaught TypeError as I had expected.
b.log();
class Bolygon {
  log() { console.log('i am bolygon'); }
}
```

## question

In some case, such as [this code(playground link)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F*%20no%20error%20because%20class%20is%20defined%20in%20advance.%20*%2F%0D%0Aclass%20Polygon%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20log()%20%7B%20console.log('i%20am%20polygon')%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20p%20%3D%20new%20Polygon()%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20no%20error%20as%20I%20had%20expected.%0D%0Ap.log()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F*%20error%20because%20class%20is%20not%20hoisted%20*%2F%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2Fconst%20b%20%3D%20new%20Bolygon()%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20Uncaught%20TypeError%20as%20I%20had%20expected.%0D%0A%2F%2Fb.log()%3B%0D%0Aclass%20Bolygon%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20log()%20%7B%20console.log('i%20am%20bolygon')%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F*%20I%20can't%20understand%20why%20new%20Hero()%20doesn't%20cause%20error.%20*%2F%0D%0Aclass%20AppComponent%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20hero%20%3D%20new%20Hero('foo')%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Hero%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(public%20name%3A%20string)%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20app%20%3D%20new%20AppComponent()%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(app.hero.name)%3B), will class be hoisted?

I can't understand why `new Hero()` doesn't cause error in below.
`class Hero` is hoisted?

```
class AppComponent {
  hero = new Hero('foo') // why no error?
}
class Hero {
  constructor(public name: string){}
}
```

Comment: Technically, classes are hoisted, but not initialized,  similar to `var`s  - http://stackoverflow.com/a/35537963/43848

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that this line:

```
hero = new Hero('foo')
```

Is only evaluated when you instantiate `AppComponent` which is after the class `Hero` has been evaluated.
However, in your 2nd code snippet this line:

```
const b = new Bolygon();
```

Is evaluated first, before the class itself has been evaluated.

If you make `AppComponent.hero` static it will cause an error:

```
class AppComponent {
  static hero = new Hero('foo') // errro: Hero is not a constructor
}
```