# Render a container based on logic React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have two containers in my App.js and the state is maintained in the Redux store.

```
 <StartGameContainer/>
 <GameContainer/>
```

The state of my app has a property called **"gameStatus"** which is set to false. I am trying to use this property to render my component in `GameContainer` if true. This property is set to true when I click a Start button in my `StartGameContainer`.

When the App initially renders it notices that this property is false. When I click on the start button it has no effect in rendering the contents from `GameContainer`. How can I achieve this or have gotten this layout wrong?

**EDIT**

**GameContainer.js**

```
const mapStateToProps = state => (
    {
        board: state.boardGame.board,
        gameStatus: state.boardGame.gameStatus
    }
);

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        initGame: () => {
            dispatch(allActions.initGame())
        },

        selectCol : (val) => {
            dispatch(allActions.dropTile(val))
        }
    }
};

const GameContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(GridCells);

class GridCells extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.initGame();
    }

    render() {
        if(this.props.gameStatus){
            return (
                <div className="game">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {this.props.board.map((row, i) => (
                            <RowCells key={i} row={row} select={this.props.selectCol}/>
                        ))}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            )
        }else{
            return(<div></div>)
        }
    }
}
```

**StartGameContainer.js**

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return{
        pickPlayer: (currPlayer) => {
            dispatch(allActions.setPlayer(currPlayer))
        }
    }
};
const StartGameContainer = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(StartGame);


class StartGame extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.players = ['myself', 'service'];
        this.selectedVal = 1;
    }

    selectedPlayer(event){
        this.selectedVal = event.target.value === 'myself' ? 1 : 2;
    }

    render(){
        let options = this.players.map((val) => {
            return (<option key={val} value={val}>{val}</option>)
        });
        return(
            <div className='startGame'>
                <select name="players" id="players" onChange={this.selectedPlayer.bind(this)}>
                    {options}
                </select>
                <button onClick= {() => {this.props.pickPlayer(this.selectedVal)}}>Start Game</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the code of GameContainer.

Comment: @ChrisCousins edited in the original question

Comment: What's the *specific* issue? Your technical description of the problem at the moment is basically "it doesn't work". Is it that the store gets updated, but the connected component isn't re-rendering? Or that the action is dispatched, but store isn't getting updated? There's a bunch of places where this issue could be happening, gotta narrow it down.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure what your Redux logic looks like... but betting your problems arise from a misunderstanding of how [hoisting](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp) works.

Try putting both your connect code lines below the class definitions:

```
class StartGame extends Component{ ... }

const StartGameContainer = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(StartGame)
```

Check out this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35537963/2847302) about how JS classes are hoisted but not initialized.

"It's never a good idea to use a class before its definition"

Here's a simplified example to help you better understand why your code is not throwing an error, but also not working properly. Consider this snippet:

```js
function logYourClass() {
  console.log(yourClass)
  var yourClass = 'all the class details'
}
logYourClass()
```

If you run this you'll notice `undefined` gets logged, and there is no "`yourClass` is not defined" ReferenceError thrown. This is because the above code is equivalent to writing:

```js
function logYourClass() {
  var yourClass
  console.log(yourClass)
  yourClass = 'all the class details'
}
logYourClass()
```

Also worth noting that ES6 `let` and `const` declaration are **not** hoisted. Try replacing the `var` in the above code with either one of these keywords and you'll see an Uncaught ReferenceError.

```js
function logYourClass() {
  console.log(yourClass)
  const yourClass = 'all the class details'
}
logYourClass()
```

Comment: @RRP did this fix your issue? Don't silently slink away without giving some feedback