# Instantiate object from inside function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, scope

Say we have a class in the global scope

```
class SampleClass {
    constructor(a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

After this declaration, the class can be instantiated in the global scope like:

```
var obj = new SampleClass(a); //works
```

But the same declaration doesn't work inside a function in the global scope, as in:

```
function sampleFunc() {
    var obj = new SampleClass(a); //doesn't work
    //...
}
```

It throws the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: SampleClass is not defined
```

How can I create an object of `SampleClass` from inside the function `sampleFunc`?

I am confused because `SampleClass` is declared in the global scope, so I expected it to be visible inside `sampleFunc`.

Comment: I get error as `"TypeError: Class constructor SampleClass cannot be invoked without 'new'`.. How did you get the error you posted? [Link](https://jsbin.com/kuyumamora/3/edit?js,console). Also the error I got, is expected and self explanatory.. You were supposed to call it like `new SampleClass(a)`..

Comment: My bad, I forgot to add the new keyword in the question, which I have in my source code. I fixed it.

Comment: Ok, then it will be a loading issue.. Probably, you are trying to call the function before the definition is available..

Comment: I can run the sampleFunc without a ReferenceError if I declare the SampleClass above sampleFunc. Are you declaring SampleClass in the same file ?

Comment: The class definition appears before the function, as in the example. Both are in the same file. However, the function is called from a point above the class definition. Is that the reason?

Comment: Ok, I moved the function that calls `sampleFunc` below the declaration of `SampleClass` and I don't get the error anymore. I didn't realize Javascript is so sensitive to the ordering of declarations.

Comment: Yes that's the problem, the class is not initialized yet so it won't work

Comment: @NetalJubalin Yes, it's in the [temporal dead zone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31222689/1048572). You cannot instantiate a class before you defined it [for good reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35537619/1048572).