# How to extend a class from the same typescript file?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to inherit a class that is in the same file but the compiler generates the following errors:

> Class 'FilterController' used before its declaration.ts(2449)
>   FilterData.ts(53, 7): 'FilterController' is declared here.
>
> (property) FilterController._typingValue: HTMLInputElement Only public
>   and protected methods of the base class are accessible via the 'super'
>   keyword.ts(2340)

```
export default class FilterData extends FilterController {
    private _dataValue: any;

    constructor(protected storageKey: string, protected typingValue: HTMLInputElement, protected containerMain: HTMLElement, protected listboxMain: HTMLElement, protected listboxSecondary: HTMLElement) {
        super(storageKey, typingValue, containerMain, listboxMain, listboxSecondary);
    }

    /*private set data(dataValue: any) { this._dataValue = dataValue; }
    private get data(): any { return this._dataValue; }*/

    public initComponent() :void {
        this.keypress();
    }

    private keypress() {
        super._typingValue.addEventListener('keyup', (_event: KeyboardEvent) => {
            //this.search(_event);
            alert("aee")
        });
    }


}

class FilterController {
    protected readonly _storageKey: string;
    protected readonly _typingValue: HTMLInputElement;
    protected readonly _containerMain: HTMLElement;
    protected readonly _listboxMain: HTMLElement;
    protected readonly _listboxSecondary: HTMLElement;

    constructor(protected storageKey: string, protected typingValue: HTMLInputElement, protected containerMain: HTMLElement, protected listboxMain: HTMLElement, protected listboxSecondary: HTMLElement){
        this._storageKey = storageKey;
        this._typingValue = typingValue;
        this._containerMain = containerMain;
        this._listboxMain = listboxMain;
        this._listboxSecondary = listboxSecondary;
    }
}
```

Comment: As the error says you're trying to use `FilterController` in the file *before* you've defined it in the file. Just move `FilterController` to the top before `FilterData`.

Comment: Some more details on Classes and hoisting within JS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35537619/why-are-es6-classes-not-hoisted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that you are using a class before it has been declared. In you case, you are extending `FilterController` before the declaration of the class.

The easiest solution to your problem is to change the order of the two classes. First declare `FilterController`, then `FilterData` which extends the first class.