# Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Class' before initialization

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have little vanila-js project. Chrome's console gives me error from title. Structure of my code is like this:

```
<script type="module">

    import * as THREE from 'https://unpkg.com/three/build/three.module.js';

    import { TrackballControls } from 'https://unpkg.com/three/examples/jsm/controls/TrackballControls.js';

    var camera, scene, renderer, controls;

    init();
    animate();

function init() {
//code here
var list_of_objects=generate_first();}

 class Color{


        constructor() {
            this.R=getRandomInt(0,255);
            this.G=getRandomInt(0,255);
            this.B=getRandomInt(0,255);
            this.hex=this.fullColorHex(this.R,this.G,this.B);
        }
//rest of code}

 function generate_first() {
        var list_of_gens=[];
        var color=new Color();}

</script>
```

Console indicates on line : `var color=new Color();`How to fix it? I have no idea why i have this problem.
PS:Yes, I've searched other topics on stack, but those topics touched frameworks or typescript. None helped me with my bug! That's why I created that topic. Please, don't leave minuses or thumbs down but help me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Classes, like variables declared with `const` and `let`, cannot be referenced before the line that initializes them runs. For example, the following is forbidden:

```
console.log(foo);
const foo = 'foo';
```

`class`es have the same rule. Here, you're calling `init` before the `class Color` line has run. The fix is to do:

```
const foo = 'foo';
console.log(foo);
```

or, in this case:

```
class Color {
  // ...
}
init(); // only call init once Color has been defined
```

Move the `Color` class up to the top, or move the `init()` call to the bottom of the script, or otherwise somehow make sure `Color` is defined by the time you call `init`.

Comment: This could explain the subtlety that **class declarations are hoisted, but not their value**. So code can use a class name before it's defined, as long as that code doesn't execute before it's defined. Details at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35537963/673991) and [stackabuse](https://stackabuse.com/hoisting-in-javascript/#hoistingclasses).