# function hoisting for inner function calls

Tags: javascript, scope, executioncontext

Please note: ^ This question is not a duplicate to a let/const question as that is unrelated. The same question remains regardless if it was `var`, `let`, or `const` since that is unrelated to the intent of the question.

---

I would really appreciate some clarification on function hoisting within another function. This is what I understand clearly so far:

This does not work because `anotherFunc` is being called in the file before it's created and `const` does not hoist before it's created.

```
const someFunc = () => {
 console.log('someFunc called');
}
   
anotherFunc(); // anotherFunc is not defined error
   
const anotherFunc = () => {
 console.log('anotherFunc called');
}
```

This works because `anotherFunc` is a **function declaration** and they are hoisted to the top as per JS rules:

```
anotherFunc(); // anotherFunc called

function anotherFunc() {
    console.log('anotherFunc called');
}
```

Doesn’t work because it’s a **function expression** and since they are assigned to a `var` variable, the variable will be hoisted to the top and undefined initially:

```
anotherFunc(); // anotherFunc is not a function at <anonymous>

var anotherFunc = function () {
    console.log('anotherFunc called');
}
```

So can someone explain to me why this works(see below)? This is a step deeper from everything explained online.

If a function is declared later but is called inside another function before it, why does it work? This has something to do with JS execution order?

```
const someFunc = () => {
    console.log('someFunc called');
    anotherFunc();
}
   
const anotherFunc = () => {
 console.log('anotherFunc called');
}

someFunc(); // 'someFunc called' 'anotherFunc called'
```

Is it because `someFunc` and `anotherFunc` are first assigned by JS in memory so then calling them later doesn't matter what order they are in?

Lastly, does this differ for const/let/var functions in the same scenario(the last one)?

Thank you so much for the clarification!

Comment: All that matters is that you call the function AFTER it has been defined. The ordering in the source code doesn't matter, just the timing.

Comment: Since you call `someFunc` after both functions have been defined, `someFunc` can call `anotherFunc`.

Comment: Thanks Barmar! But I'm wondering a bit deeper than that. Like what exactly happens in JavaScript? Why can `someFunc` call `anotherFunc` after it has been defined? Does JS store them first in memory and then when `anotherFunc` is called it's simply getting a function already available in that memory? Or what? What is the order of events, this is what I'm really curious about.

Comment: They're just variables. After a variable has been given a value, you can refer to it.

Comment: When you execute `anotherFunc()`, it just looks up the name `anotherFunc`, gets its value, and calls it.

Comment: It's no different from if you wrote `console.log(someVariable);` and the variable was assigned after the function.

Comment: Well there is a difference in that case because if it's a `var` it would undefined, otherwise you would get errors for `const` and `let`.

Comment: No it wouldn't. Define the function, then define the variable, then call the function, and it works.

Comment: `function foo() { console.log(variable); } let variable = "bar"; foo();`

Comment: Ah that's what you mean. Yeah I see that works. But still I'm curious what happens under the hood.

Comment: Nothing special happens. When you do `const functionName = something` it evaluates the `something` expression and puts it into the variable `functionName`. You can then call the function after that's done.

Comment: The important point is that JavaScript doesn't require names to be declared before you refer to them in function definitions. Only before the code that refers to them is executed.

Comment: Function hoisting is a special case that allows you to refer to functions in the same scope before they're defined.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript's Execution Context has two components:

- Memory (Variable Environment)
- Code (Thread of Execution) - Sync & Single-Threaded meaning JS can only do things one by one and in a certain orders(one after the other)

So the reason this works:

```
const someFunc = () => {
    console.log('someFunc called');
    anotherFunc();
}
   
const anotherFunc = () => {
 console.log('anotherFunc called');
}

someFunc(); // 'someFunc called' 'anotherFunc called'
```

...is because JS first allocates `someFunc` and `anotherFunc` to `undefined` within memory(as I had suspected in my question). Function declarations are also saved here as the entire function.

This is the memory allocation phase.
Then it runs the code execution phase.

JS goes lines by line and adds the values to the variables.

If the value for the key saved in memory is a function it creates another inner Execution Context and once again runs a Memory Allocation and Code Execution Phase for that particular function.

So in my case:

1. Execution Context is created.
2. `someFunc` and `anotherFunc` are allocated to memory as `undefined`.
3. `someFunc` gets called and a new inner Execution Context is created.
4. `console.log` runs.
5. `anotherFunc` gets saved to `undefined` in memory within `someFunc` execution context. Code execution runs and `anotherFunc` gets called and another Execution Context gets created for that function. Since it has no variable etc. it just runs the `console.log`.
6. `anotherFunc` is complete and its Execution Context gets removed. It gives its' power back to `someFunc`(this also happens when a function returns).
7. `someFunc` is complete and it's Execution Context gets removed. It gives its` power back to the main JS Execution Context.(this also happens when a function returns).

This guy explains it all very clearly: https://youtu.be/iLWTnMzWtj4

Comment: `const`, `let` and `class` are not initialised with `undefined` when they are created, they are left uninitialised.

Comment: Yes you are right. `const` and `let` are still hoisted though and created in memory but they are not initialized until the code is run. This called the "temporal dead zone". Which is why you would get a Reference error if you called them before they are declared.

Comment: Although I didn't know about `class`. Really? JS doesn't natively have classes, they are just functions underneath so I wonder why they don't get hoisted up, at least similarly to function expressions ie automatically set as `undefined`.

Comment: See [Why are ES6 classes not hoisted?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35537963/1048572) :-)

Comment: Ah ok, thanks! :)