# Advantages of using let over var within a function

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, encapsulation, var

Say I have a piece of code like this:

```
const number = 3;

function fooFunction() {
  let numberTwo = 5;
  var answer = number + numberTwo;
  return answer;
}

finalAnswer = fooFunction();

console.log(finalAnswer);
```

Assuming an ES2015 compatible browser, what would be the advantages/disadvantages of using the above code, over:

```
const number = 3;

function fooFunction() {
  var numberTwo = 5;
  var answer = number + numberTwo;
  return answer;
}

finalAnswer = fooFunction();

console.log(finalAnswer);
```

Are there any advantages or disadvantages, given they both return the same number?

Comment: As per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11444416/668501) they are identical within a function like yours

Comment: What about from a security and performance point of view?

Comment: Per your usage above, there is no difference.

Comment: If there were a difference in security or performance they would not be identical

Comment: "*What about from a security and performance point of view?*" The difference between `let` and `var` is scope. Not performance.

Comment: it's just scoping (var is function scope, let is block scope). The compiler will take care of hoisting and optimization.

Comment: Indeed. Yet it seems to me as though the `let` function would be more secure, as the data would not be accessible outside the function. Is this correct or incorrect? If not, why doesn't it make a difference? Also, doesn't hoisting carry a performance hit? I would have thought it would.

Comment: `var` is function scope and not visible outside the function. `let`, being block scope means it isn't necessarily visible throughout the entire function, but they're both local to your function...

Comment: In your example, `var answer` is not available outside of the `fooFunction()` block.

Comment: Yet `var` variables are hoisted outside the function scope and available to the interpreter at a global level, while `let` is not. Is that not correct?

Comment: no, `var` is hoisted to the top of the function, not outside the function :)

Comment: But surely if a `let` defined variable remains uninitialised outside the function in which it is called, which seems to be the case, this is more secure than `var`, since the *data* is not accessible to anything but the function itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have mentioned, in your example you can use `let` and `var` interchangeably. The difference is that `let` is block-scoped and `var` is not.

For example with `var` you can do this (prints 'foo'):

```js
function printFoo(param) {
  if (param) {
    var x = "foo";
  }

  console.log(x);
}

printFoo("hello");
```

You cannot do this with `let` because `let x` is scoped to the `if` block and therefore is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Within the code sample you've provided, the two are interchangeable.  Where `let` comes in handy is in limiting the scope to block-level as opposed to function-level.  Using `let` inside of a `for` loop, for example.

It's worth noting that variables created with the `var` keyword are hoisted, whereas variables created with the `let` keyword are not.

There is an excellent breakdown of this topic by Kyle Simpson on David Walsh's blog: https://davidwalsh.name/for-and-against-let#implicit-hazards

Comment: technically, `let` variables are hoisted, but not referenceable. see temporal dead zone.  `In ECMAScript 2015, let will hoist the variable to the top of the block. However, referencing the variable in the block before the variable declaration results in a ReferenceError. The variable is in a "temporal dead zone" from the start of the block until the declaration is processed.`

Comment: (see [Are variables declared with let or const not hoisted in ES6?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31219420/1048572) for more detailed discussion)