# Strange behavior of ES6 destructuring in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, destructuring

## Environment

**Google Chrome**: 61.0.3163.79 beta （64 bit） (cohort: Beta)

**JavaScript Engine**: V8 6.1.534.32

## Code

In Chrome, open a new tab, type following code one-by-one in the console:

```
let [a = b, b = 1] = [];

typeof a;

let a = 'other value';

a = 'other value';
```

The output is:
[image]

## Question

Can someone explain why the 1st statement `let [a = b, b = 1] = []` make variable `a` to be **'a is not defined'** and **'Identifier 'a' has already been declared'** at the same time?

What is the magic in the 1st statement execution?

Is it related to the ES6 [“Temporal Dead Zone” (TDZ)](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-let-const-and-temporal-dead-zone-in-depth)?

## Update

The sample code is invalid, I just want to know the reason about the outputs. :)

Comment: Is this a valid syntax? You are not exactly destructing anything. For example, `[a, b] = [1, 2]` would destructure just fine

Comment: Hi @VamshiGudipati, yes the code is indeed invaild invalid, I am asking the reason for the outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is related to the temporal dead zone - twice actually.

### Issue one

You are trying to use `b` as a default value for `a` before it has been initialised. The evaluation goes from left to right, and while [both `a` and `b` are already declared](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31219420/1048572) they do get initialised in order. Using `let [a = 1, b = a] = []` would work.

### Issue two

An error was thrown in the global scope between the declaration of the variable and its initialisation. You can reduce the test case to

```
let a = (_ => { throw; })();
```

This does declare the variable `a`, but never initialises it because an exception happens before. Usually - in local scopes - that's not a problem, because the scope in which `a` was declared here is left with the exception. It's different in the global scope - the variable stays forever declared but uninitialised. It's **dead in eternity** (the temporal zone is "forever"). See [here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41256149/1048572).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign b to a, before you've even declared b.

Use

```
let [b =1, a = b] = [];
```

The reason it says `a` has already been declared is because it's declaring `a` first, and then it tries to assign `b` to it (which has not been declared yet) and then the code errors, but `a` has already been declared