# Should I declare a variable using LET globally for a function that runs constantly?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Most relevant answers here do not refer to *let*, which is block scoped, but to *var*, which is hoisted. I can't seem to get a definitive answer to this.

I have a variable declared globally that initializes once:

```
let firePaused = false;
```

and then a function in the keyboard handler that is running everytime I press a button:

```
function actOnKeyPress() {
  if (rightPressed) {
    game.hero.rotate(game.hero.speed);
  } else if (leftPressed) {
    game.hero.rotate(-game.hero.speed);
  }
  if (!firePressed) {
    firePaused = false;
  }
  if (firePressed && options.numberOfBullets > 0) {
    if (!firePaused) {
      fireBullet();
      firePaused = true;
    }
  }
}
```

(not relevant to the question, but it's purpose is to only allow the player to fire once, there needs to be a keyup event before they can fire again)

By the rules of clean code I should declare the variable at the top of the function... BUT that means it will be redeclared everytime I press a button.

It says here https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-declare-variables-javascript/

> Initialization: When you declare a variable it is automatically
>   initialized, which means memory is allocated for the variable by the
>   JavaScript engine.

So I would be creating a whole new variable each time the *let* keyword is used.

Should I go to the bother of writing a conditional at the start of the function to check if `firePaused` is declared yet, and if not declare it? That seems total overkill.

Comment: It seems like you have a global variable, `game`. What about `game.state.firePaused`? That way, if you put all gamestate-related variables there, you could even easily save the game.

Comment: is it possible that you could return true or false instead of setting a variable?

Comment: That Sitepoint note is at best misleading, and in my opinion it's simply wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are attempting to maintain a character's (hero) state in multiple locations. This will become more and more difficult to maintain in a global scope as each character's actions / states will add to the global variables.

As per @jeff-huijsmans suggestion, I believe you should maintain the state inside your `game` object.

This could be defined in a few ways:

1. `game.state.firePaused` - This locks your game state to a single character, but will better contain the state of a character shooting.
2. `game.hero.firePaused` - This allows each character to maintain their own shooting state. This also has the added benefit of being able to add more characters with firing states.

*As an aside, it looks like most of the answers here are attempting to address the scope issue. Defining variables globally and attempting to maintain a state outside of a function becomes very difficult to understand/read/test. There will be a lot of opinions on this topic. Fortunately for your root issue you can avoid this by using your pre-existing state object.*

Answer (score 4):

If your variable is declared in the global scope, then it doesn't really matter if you use `let` or `var`.

These are functionally identical:

```js
let myVar = 123;
function doStuff() {
  console.log(myVar);
}
doStuff();
```

```js
var myVar = 123;
function doStuff() {
  console.log(myVar);
}
doStuff();
```

The difference between `var` and `let` becomes significant when you're declaring them in blocks:

```js
if(true) {
  var foo = 1;
}
if(true) {
  let bar = 2;
}

console.log("var foo:", foo);
console.log("let bar:", bar);
```

As you can see, the `let` declaration is restricted to its wrapping block scope. The `var` declaration ignores block scope.

Comment: Actually I recommend to always [use `var` for global variables even in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836796/what-is-the-use-case-for-var-in-es6), as [`let` and `const` can lead to problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36140252/1048572).

Comment: @Bergi: Isn't `window` a bit of a hack, used instead of proper scope manipulation / usage?

Comment: I don't care about the variable being available on `window`, the problem is with [eternally dead variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41256149/1048572). (found the right link now).

Answer (score 2):

### This question really has nothing to do with `let` vs. `var`, per se - it's about scope in general.

Variables should be declared in the smallest scope that keeps the program functional.  Global variables should be a last resort.

So, in your case, you don't need a Global variable to achieve your goal of not re-declaring the variable upon each function call. You just need to create another scope. Since all code should be kept out of the Global scope in the first place, your code should already have at least one sub-scope, which is often achieved with an **[Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)**, which creates the **["Module Pattern"](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html)**:

```
(function(){
  let firePaused = false; // This is scoped to the entire module, but not Global

  function actOnKeyPress() {
    if (rightPressed) {
      game.hero.rotate(game.hero.speed);
    } else if (leftPressed) {
      game.hero.rotate(-game.hero.speed);
    }
    if (!firePressed) {
      firePaused = false;
    }
    if (firePressed && options.numberOfBullets > 0) {
      if (!firePaused) {
        fireBullet();
        firePaused = true;
      }
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: Aren't coding conventions a little out of "scope", for this question?

Comment: @Cerbrus Not when those "patterns" ("conventions" are something else entirely) modify scope.

Comment: Nitpicking: _"all code should be kept out of the Global scope"_ < That's a convention. _How_ you do that, is a by implementing a certain pattern.

Comment: @Cerbrus (more nitpicking) That's a "best-practice". A "convention" is a generally accepted way of doing something (i.e. naming conventions). There are many ways to avoid the Global scope.

Comment: You, Sir, just out-nitpicked me.

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not create a global variable (and not with `let` anyway).
Yes, you should declare it outside of the function if you want to have it shared between calls.

You can use a closure for that, with any kind of module pattern - from ES6 module to IIFE to simple block scope.

```
// ES6 module
let firePaused = false;
export function actOnKeyPress() {
  // use `firePaused`
}
```

```
// IIFE
var actOnKeyPress = (function() {
  let firePaused = false;
  return function actOnKeyPress() {
    // use `firePaused`
  };
}());
```

```
// block scope
var actOnKeyPress;
{
  let firePaused = false;
  actOnKeyPress = function actOnKeyPress() {
    // use `firePaused`
  };
}
```