# How can I re-use a variable after throwing an exception during initialization in node console?

Tags: javascript

Concretely, this happened (node v12.22.9):

```
me@my-machine:~/Projects/.../my-projects$ node
Welcome to Node.js v12.22.9.
Type ".help" for more information.
> let foo = (function(){ throw new Error() })()
Uncaught Error
    at REPL1:1:30
> foo
Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined
> foo = 1
Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined
> let foo = 1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'foo' has already been declared
> let bar
undefined
> bar = (function(){ throw new Error() })()
Uncaught Error
    at REPL6:1:26
> bar
undefined
> bar = 1
1
> let bar = 1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'bar' has already been declared
```

If you see, I cannot:

- Retrieve the value of `foo`, since it is not defined.
- Assign a new value to `foo`, since it is not defined.
- Define it again (with or without initial value), **since it is already defined**.

This renders the identifier `foo` completely unusable (until I close the console session). This, however, does *not* happen to `bar`, since I don't initialize it to an expression throwing an exception (I assign `bar` to an expression throwing an exception *after* the variable `bar` is defined).

Is this a bug or an expected behaviour? is there a way I can clear this behaviour (without restarting the repl) and re-use `foo`?

Comment: Update your node version. This was fixed some time ago iirc.

Comment: I can find [chrome-console-already-declared-variables-throw-undefined-reference-errors-for-l](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255090/chrome-console-already-declared-variables-throw-undefined-reference-errors-for-l) - this behavior has also annoyed me for ages.

Comment: …or maybe not: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8309 But in Chrome devtools console, you can not redeclare lexical bindings

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable with `var` instead of `let`.

```
Welcome to Node.js v16.18.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> let foo = (function(){ throw new Error() })()
Uncaught Error
    at REPL1:1:30
> foo = 1
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'foo' before initialization
```

Using `var`:

```
Welcome to Node.js v16.18.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> var foo = (function(){ throw new Error() })()
Uncaught Error
    at REPL1:1:30
> typeof(foo)
'undefined'
> foo
undefined
> foo = 1
1
```