# Does 'let' override a global declaration and throws a ReferenceError?

Tags: javascript, scope, ecmascript-6, global, let

I was going through the Difference between `var` and `let` documentation example and was testing that when an undeclared variable is invoked, the global scope automatically provides a declaration for it (that's why the following snippet does not throw an error in any of the variables):

```js
x = 3;
console.log(x);

(function() {
  y=x+39;
})()
console.log(y);
```

However, when one variable is declared with `let` after the assignment in the same global scope:

```js
x=3;
let x = 42;
console.log(x);
```

One of the following errors is thrown:

> **ReferenceError**: `x` is not defined (Chromium)
>
> **ReferenceError**: can't access lexical declaration `x` before initialization (Firefox)

I understand that `let` does not allow `x` to hoist, but since it was previously referenced (implying an automatic declaration from the global scope) shouldn't in this case a re-declaration happen?

> **SyntaxError**: Identifier`x` has already been declared

And therefore the error above thrown?

I also understand that in **strict mode** the first snippet would throw a **ReferenceError**, so does this mean that `let` forces this particular rule of strict mode (all variables need to be declared) upon the global scope?

Comment: [`let` is hoisted as well](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31219420/1048572), you just are accessing it during the temporal dead zone. I don't see what strict mode has to do with this.

Comment: @Bergi I was not fully aware of the [TDZ](http://jsrocks.org/2015/01/temporal-dead-zone-tdz-demystified/), I was assuming that a non declared variable would be automatically declared in the global scope (at this time the [docs](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/480/scope/1574/difference-between-var-and-let#t=201701031850353755045) only show a double `let` declaration). Since accessing a variable before its own `let` declaration throws a **ReferenceError**, I thought that a strict-mode-behavior/rule was related, but now I understand that it is due to `let` hoisting the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, it's weird behavior. The reason it's giving those errors is because it thinks you're trying to assign the value `3` to your `let` variable instead of the global value.  As others mentioned, this leads to the temporal deadzone issue with hoisting.

> The variables are created when their containing Lexical Environment is
>   instantiated but **may not be accessed in any way until the variable’s
>   LexicalBinding is evaluated**

- [Source (ECMAScript 8th edition)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-let-and-const-declarations)

This code shows where placing code causes the TDZ:

```
// Accessing `x` here before control flow evaluates the `let x` statement
// would throw a ReferenceError due to TDZ.
// console.log(x);

let x = 42;
// From here on, accessing `x` is perfectly fine!
console.log(x);
```

You can see that wrapping the `let` inside its own block block fixes it:

```
x=3;
{
let x = 42;
console.log(x); // 42
}
```

Alternatively, you can define the global explicitly on the `window` object:

```
window.x=3;

let x = 42;
console.log(x);  // 42
```

Comment: what about:
`
var a = 1;
function fn() {
  console.log(a);
  let a = 2;
}

fn();
`

Comment: @AntonYaskevich Same thing, you are trying to log `x` before the statement is evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

Did you have a look at the `let` docs at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)? They describe a **temporal dead zone and errors with let**.

ES6 does hoist a `let` variable to the top of its scope. Differently to `var` variable, when using `let` you must not access the variable before it is declared. Doing so fail with a `ReferenceError` (a.k.a. *let's temporal dead zone*).

Comment: but isn't the x initialised to 3 which defaults to global declaration in the first statement. So, it should have a reference at statement #2 regardless of whether let hoists the variable or not. 
What are your views?

Comment: `let x;` is hoisted to the top of the scope - global scope in this case. The statement `x=3;` cannot create a new `var` as in this scope the name is already reserved for our `let`. It cannot access the variable `x` either as it is not declared yet.

Comment: So, this is the kind of behaviour that prevents variables from using before declaration. This makes sense. However, I'll have to look more into it to be sure. Thanks

Comment: @KonstantinA.Magg your words in [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41451181/does-let-override-a-global-declaration-and-throws-a-referenceerror/41452809#comment70109192_41451275) allowed me to understand it better than the words in your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Konstantin A. Magg explained, that's because `let` variables are hoisted and attempts to reference them before initialization throw (temporal dead zone).

If you don't want this, you can split the code into different scripts:

```html
<script>
x = 3;
console.log(x); // 3
</script>

<script>
let x = 42;
console.log(x); // 42
</script>
```

Note `x = 3` will throw in strict mode.