# Why does using a let variable in a new block before reassigning it error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have the following document https://www.codementor.io/cchilder/draft/bcgnrvw5p where I try to explain this:

```
// declare variables
const x = 1;
let y = 2;
var z = 3;

console.log(`Global scope - x, y, z: ${x}, ${y}, ${z}`);

if (true) {
    console.log(`A new block scope - x, y, z: ${x}, ${y}, ${z}`);

    // redeclare variables
    // const x = 4;
    let y = 5;
    var z = 6;
}
```

At the top of the `if` block, `y` is not defined:

```
$ node variables.js 
Global scope - x, y, z: 1, 2, 3
/Users/cchilders/variables.js:9
    console.log(`A new block scope - x, y, z: ${x}, ${y}, ${z}`);
                                                      ^

ReferenceError: y is not defined
```

I wasn't expecting this, and don't know how to explain. I have now:

When we redeclare these variables using the same names, we remove access to those names inside the block scope:

```
...

if (true) {
    // inside this block, we lost access to the old x and y because they're going to be redeclared inside this block scope...but we can't use them yet, they haven't been declared yet
    console.log(`A new block scope - x, y, z: ${x}, ${y}, ${z}`);

    // redeclare variables
    const x = 4;
    let y = 5;
    // now we can use the new x and y, 4 and 5 respectively
    var z = 6;
}
...
```

Why does this happen, and how exactly does the JavaScript/Node interpreter read the code that causes this error?

Comment: This SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219420/are-variables-declared-with-let-or-const-not-hoisted-in-es6) explains this behavior.

Comment: tl;dr: You cannot access a variable defined with `let` before it was assigned a value. The `y` in the block shadows the outer `y`, i.e. `y` in `console.log(`A new block scope - x, y, z: ${x}, ${y}, ${z}`);` refers to the inner `y`, which doesn't have a value yet and therefore throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's okay to use the old `x` and `y` in an new block as long as the new block belongs to the old scope, but since you've created another `y` in the new block with `let`, according to ES6, the new `y` will overwrite the old `y` with a 'unassigned' value, once it get visited without assigning, an error come out.

```
if(true) {
    console.log(y);
    {
        const x;
        let y;
        var z;
        // your code
    }
}
```