# Link to a promise of async function inside of it

Tags: javascript, async-await

Consider this simplified code

```js
;(async () => {
  const a = [1, 2]
  const p = a.map(async (v, i) => {
    if (i === 0) {
      return await 1
    }
    return await p[i - 1]
  })
  console.log(await Promise.all(p))
})()
```

In V8 (Chrome/NodeJS) it rices an error "ReferenceError: p is not defined"

In firefox it just gives nothing

The question: is what is wrong with it?

Comment: Whats the sense of this code?

Comment: It might help if you could (also) post your actual code, not just this simplified one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you meant `a[i-1]`. The `p` variable is [not yet initialised](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31222689/1048572) when the `map` callback is executed. Firefox may not yet implement the temporal dead zone because of backcompat concerns.

Your code might (should) work when you accessed `p` asynchronously, that is after having `await`ed something else:

```
const p = a.map(async (v, i) => {
  if (i === 0) {
    return await 1
  }
  await void 0; // delay until `p` is available
  return await p[i - 1]
})
```

However I would consider that to be horrible and confusing code. If you want to do something sequentially in an asynchronous function, use a standard loop:

```
for (const v of a)
  await 1;
```

and if you want to run some tasks in parallel, use `Promise.all` but make sure that they don't depend on each other.

Comment: This is a simplified example, so actually await in the line before is what I need. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
return await p[i - 1]
```

`p` is used inside the `.map` function and isn't available when it is called.

You probably mean:

```
return await a[i - 1]
```