# var and let redeclaration in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

As we all know:

> If an identifier has already been defined in a scope, then using the identifier in a let declaration inside that scope causes an error to be thrown.   -- [《YDFJS》](https://leanpub.com/understandinges6/read#leanpub-auto-block-level-declarations)

and `var` doesn't have such limit:

```
var a = 1;
var a = 2; // works fine
```

Snippet below will fail,

```
let a = 1;
var a = 2; // SyntaxError: Identifier 'a' has already been declared
```

Because of the "Variable Hoisting", I think this code will be translated like this:

```
var a;
let a = 1;
a = 2;
```

so, the SyntaxError exception should be thrown by the first line: `let a = 1`, **but in both Node and Chrome, the exception was thrown by the second line: `var a = 2`**.

I got confused, why is `var` doing the redeclaration checking and throw an exception here?

Comment: `let` and `var` both are being declared in same scope. So first `let` will declare the variable `a` and then the `var a` will execute. As variable `a` has already been declared using `let`, you will get error for `var`.

Comment: This happens because `let` is hoisted as well and is in *temporal dead zone*.

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with hoisting (although clearly "both" variables are declared in the same scope), you just get the exception on the *second declaration* with the same name.

Comment: @estus I have read this question, but in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_dead_zone_and_errors_with_let#Temporal_Dead_Zone_and_errors_with_let) and [Specifation](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-let-and-const-declarations), clarified that let do not hoist.

Comment: It is 'hoisted' in broader sense of this word, while ES2015 provides tech definition. *The variables are created when their containing Lexical Environment is instantiated but may not be accessed in any way until the variable’s LexicalBinding is evaluated*, I guess it's more correct explanation of what's going on. Until the declaration is evaluated, it's in dead zone and cannot be read or written.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you very much, I think Javascript just throw the exception at the *second one*. Could you please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46691231/how-does-javascript-declare-function-parameters), haven't received a satisfying answer yet.