# Is babel producing subtly incorrect code for let bindings?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm seeing a difference in behavior between native es6 and transpiled code.

According to the MDN docs, this code should result in a `ReferenceError` because I try to use a `let-bound variable` before it is defined.

```
let a = b; //expect ReferenceError at runtime
let b = 1;
```

As expected, running this results in a `ReferenceError` when I run it in something that natively supports es6, such as Chrome Developer Tools. But if I transpile that with babel, it produces code that doesn't result in a runtime error [(Live demo)](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=DYUwLgBAhhC8ECMDcAoUkFwgRlUA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015&targets=&version=6.26.0):

```
"use strict";

var a = b; //no error. Both a & b are undefined
var b = 1;
```

The behavior of the transpiled code contradicts what the MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_Dead_Zone_and_errors_with_let) say *(emphasis mine)*:

> In ECMAScript 2015, `let` bindings are not subject to `Variable Hoisting`,
>   which means that `let` declarations do not move to the top of the
>   current execution context. Referencing the variable in the block
>   before the initialization results in a `ReferenceError` **(contrary to a
>   variable declared with `var`, which will just have the undefined value).**

So I'm wondering:

1. Is this by design and is there some aspect I'm missing?
2. Is there a way to get a compile-time failure for this, rather than a runtime ReferenceError or a silent failure of 'undefined'. I notice I get a compile-time error binding to a non-existent variable. Perhaps it could also fail for a not-yet-declared variable?

   ```
   let d = e; //compile error: e is not defined
   ```

*Note: there's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219420/are-variables-declared-with-let-or-const-not-hoisted-in-es6) but I don't think it answers this (or it did but I misunderstood).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this snippet

```
let a = b;
let b = 1;
```

`b` is in temporal dead zone. This behaviour cannot be emulated in transpiled code.

To my knowledge, Babel currently doesn't have a plugin to warn against this TDZ issue. Until it will be possible to handle this problem with Babel itself, it can be detected with ESLinter [`no-use-before-define`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-use-before-define) rule.

Comment: (It can be emulated, but at a significant performance expense)