# Looks like hoisting is working in React Native with const

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I noticed one interesting thing in react native. I thought that const and let does not support hoisting in ES6.
How is it possible to use const **styles** above its define?

```
    render() {
        const { repos } = this.state;
        const reposList = repos.map((rep, index) => {
            return (
                    <Text>{rep.name}</Text>
            )
        });

        return (
                <View style={styles.container}>  <-- styles should not be defined
                    {reposList}
                </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
    welcome: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 10,
    },
    instructions: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#333333',
        marginBottom: 5,
    },
});
```

Is it because of hoisting mechanism in React Native?

Comment: All declarations are hoisted in javascript. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31222689/6731368).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is really "true". There exists a temporal dead zone in let/const. var hoists because the compiler afaik reads LHS assignments, stores them in memory, and then goes through reading RHS assignments. I am not sure how the compiler reads const/let but if you attempt to use a let/const before it's declaration you will get a temporal dead zone error.

his issue is not hoisting, he has a class defined, and a styles object defined in the same file. the class isn't invoked, just defined.

Comment: Agreed, not really a hoisting issues. Calling `render()` before `styles` is defined would cause an error. *Defining* `render()` before `styles` is not.

Comment: what @a2441918 posted should answer your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have render defined in a class, the class is just defined not executed so it can see the styles you create below it. it's not really hoisting.