# Getting error while using const ,I am little confused in using const

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm wondering what is the difference between let and const in ECMAScript 6. Both of them are block scoped

Comment: There is indeed [no difference between them with regard to scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31219420/1048572).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between let and const is that once you bind a value/object to a variable using const, you can't reassign to that variable. Example:

```
const something = {};
something = 10; // Error.

let somethingElse = {};
somethingElse = 1000; // This is fine.
```

Note that const doesn't make something immutable.

```
const myArr = [];
myArr.push(10); // Works fine.
```

Probably the best way to make an object (shallowly) immutable at the moment is to use `Object.freeze()` on it.