# What happens to the let variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have executed the following code and I found that I was unable to access the variable all the time in global scope.

```
 console.log(b); let b = 1;
VM12265:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: b is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13
(anonymous) @ VM12265:1
let b = 1; console.log(b);
VM12318:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'b' has already been declared
    at <anonymous>:1:1
(anonymous) @ VM12318:1
console.log(b);
VM12368:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: b is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13
```

I would like to know what happened to the variable b in step 3 once the step 1 and step 2 is executed.

Comment: `let` does not define variables for global scope

Comment: Were the 2nd and 3rd one done in same session ?

Comment: This is what I was looking for http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations-static-semantics-early-errors
Thanks for sharing @gurvinder372

Comment: similar reference at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219420/are-variables-declared-with-let-or-const-not-hoisted-in-es6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the **first one**

> console.log(b); let b = 1; VM12265:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: b is
>   not defined
>       at :1:13 (anonymous) @ VM12265:1

`Let`'s **binding is not created till they are initialized** and hence no reference is created. You accessed the value in [temporal zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219420/are-variables-declared-with-let-or-const-not-hoisted-in-es6)

---

> let b = 1; console.log(b); VM12318:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier
>   'b' has already been declared
>       at :1:1 (anonymous) @ VM12318:1

For the **second one**, as the message says, *b has already been declared* already. As per [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations-static-semantics-early-errors)

> It is a Syntax Error if the **BoundNames of BindingList contains any
>   duplicate entries**.

Answer (score 1):

`let` does not define variables for the global scope. You can declare `let` variable once at the beginning of the block scope and set the variable to a new value without attempting to re-declare the variable  using `let` more than once to avoid error

```js
{
  let b;

  try {
    console.log(b);
    b = 1;
    console.log(b);
    b = 2;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message)
  }
  console.log(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared variable `b`

2 ways:

1. use `var` instead of `let` (That is because of JS Hoisting)
2. declare `b` first then use it after

Answer (score -1):

I have checked in both the cases its working for me.

```
let b = 1;
var b1 = 2;
console.log(b);
console.log(b1);
```

Comment: I was looking for the riddle for step 3 not step 1