# Why does re-declaring an argument inside of a try/catch throw a ReferenceError?

Tags: javascript

I mistakenly wrote a re-declaration of an argument as a `const` in a function and instead of throwing `SyntaxError: Identifier 'bar' has already been declared` I ended up with `ReferenceError: bar is not defined.`.

What causes this behaviour? It wasn't the expected error, and left me confused for a few minutes.

Example code:

```
function foo(bar) {
  try {
      console.log(bar);
      const bar = 123;
  } catch(err) { console.log(err) }
}
foo(456);
```

If I don't wrap the declaration in a try/catch, I get (what I believe to be) the expected error.

Comment: [Temporal dead zone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_Dead_Zone_and_errors_with_let)

Comment: It's not a redeclaration if it's not in the same (block) scope.

Comment: useful to understanding is this answer :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/31222689/125981 see who wrote that one :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Constants are block-scoped, much like variables defined using the let statement.

From [this MDN article.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

Since you wrapped `bar` inside a block of braces, its definition is relative to that block. And because you have another `bar` declaration inside of that block, despite being after the call to it, the compiler will attempt to use this newly defined `bar` instead of the passed-in parameter. Rename them as separate parameters to mitigate confusion, since one can assume they are holding different data because of your declaration.

Answer (score 9):

It's a myth that `const` and `let` aren't hoisted at all. They're **half**-hoisted. :-) That is: Within a block, if `const bar` or `let bar` (or `class bar { }` for that matter) appears anywhere in that block, then `bar` cannot be used prior to that declaration in the block — even if it exists in a containing scope. This area between the beginning of the block and the declaration is called the *Temporal Dead Zone*:

```
function foo(bar) {
  // `bar` is fine here
  try {
      // Temporal Dead Zone, `bar` cannot be used here
      console.log(bar);
      // End of TDZ
      const bar = 123;
      // `bar` would be fine here
  } catch(err) { console.log(err) }
}
foo(456);
```

Answer (score 8):

Because `const` declarations are block scoped, the `const bar` declaration gets hoisted to the start of the block. (Just after `try {`)

That means that `bar` isn't actually *defined* when you try to log it, because the hoisting *overrides / hides* the parameter `bar`.

Comment: I guess that makes some sense. Confused the crap outta me tho when I saw the error. doesn't seem intuitive (to me at least) when trying to figure out where I effed up.

Comment: Yea, I had to look at it twice, as well.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from here https://tylermcginnis.com/videos/var-let-const/

> var is function scoped and if you try to use a variable declared with
>   var before the actual declaration, you'll just get undefined. const
>   and let are blocked scoped and if you try to use a const or let
>   variable before the declaration you'll get a reference error.

Comment: but it is already defined in the argument list. remove the try/catch and you get a SyntaxError. So is the try/catch block ignoring the argument list at that point? is that expected?

Comment: I guess it is. block scope bit me for the first time :P