# Why doesn't const App = App || {}; work but using var does?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In the past I have used

```
var App = App || {};
```

to assign or instantiate a common App object in various js scripts loaded separately into the browser.

However, using `let` and `const` instead of `var` throws a reference error:

```
const App = App || {}; // or let App = App || {};

Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined
at <anonymous>:1:11
```

What's going on here? If I want to continue using this pattern, do I have to stick to `var`?

Comment: Well if you think about it, declaring a new constant called "App" if there's a symbol "App" already defined doesn't make sense anyway.

Comment: As stated in the question, let also throws the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because when you are declaring a variable using `let` or a constant, the variable is in the [temporal dead zone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_dead_zone_and_errors_with_let) before being initialized.

In other words, trying `let foo = foo` will throw an error because `foo` is still in the temporal dead zone, and cannot be used. The same goes for `const`.

Note also that a variable defined whith `let` or a constant defined with `const` cannot share its name space in the same scope with another variable, be it with `let`, `const`, or `var`.

Comment: If you also try to declare it beforehand (for instance, in a generator fashion that might return null), it throws an `already declared` error. I didn't think it would do that.

Comment: Thanks! I found this post after reading your answer. Helped further understand what was happening: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219420/are-variables-declared-with-let-or-const-not-hoisted-in-es6

Comment: I'm glad I could help you :)

Answer (score 4):

When javascript engine sees the statement, `var App = App || {}`, it breaks the statement down as follows:

```
var App;
App = App || {};
```

Due to variable hoisting, `var App = App || {}` is broken down into two parts.

1. Declaration: `var App`
2. Assignment: `App = App || {}`

The `let` and `const` declarations on the other hand, don't involve variable hoisting. Hence, the `ReferenceError`, as no variable called App exists yet.

Answer (score 0):

`var` is behaving differently than `let` or `const`.

In case of `var`, JS engine first creates a variables definitions, allocate memory space for them and initialize them with an `undefined` value. Only then it start executing the code line by line.

In case of `let` or `const`, it initialize it to `undefined` only when the declaration actually happens (and only if there is no immediately assignment).

In your example, the variable `App` is still in the **[Temporal Dead Zone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)** and trying to access it at that point results in a Reference Error.