# When and why to use these various Java Script function declaration formats?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions, function-expression, javascript-function-declaration

What are the differences between the following function declaration formats?
When is it more correct to use which?

From a beginner's perspective, and a high level (non-deep) point of view, they all three appear to work the same - hence it makes things feel confusing and demands the question.

1.

```
const counter1 = function(num) {
    var x = 0;
    while (x < num) {
        console.log(x);
        x ++;
    };
    return 0;
};
```

2.

```
function counter2(num) {
    var x = 0;
    while (x < num) {
        console.log(x);
        x ++;
    };
    return 0;
};
```

3.

```
const counter3 = (num) => {
    var x = 0;
    while (x < num) {
        console.log(x);
        x ++;
    };
    return 0;
};
```

All of them *appear* to behave the same.

Comment: Comapared to **1.**, the **3.** has the additional restrictions/features an arrow function provides: arrow functions not not have their own `this`, `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target`.

Comment: Always use #2 to get hoisting. It's also the shortest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more than a few differences between your three examples actually.

So, for one, you have to be careful using const for your function declarations.

```
counter1(5); // counter1 is undefined, this will fail
const counter1 = function(num) {
    var x = 0;
    while (x < num) {
        console.log(x);
        x ++;
    };
    return 0;
};
```

Whereas the function will be hoisted and available for use (Edit: technically `let` and `const` are also hoisted, but they aren't initialized so you cannot access them before they are declared, more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219420/are-variables-declared-with-let-or-const-not-hoisted-in-es6).

```
counter2(5); // works fine
function counter2(num) {
    var x = 0;
    while (x < num) {
        console.log(x);
        x ++;
    };
    return 0;
};
```

Also note that `const` prohibits reassigning the variable, so you couldn't go say `const counter1 = {}` later down the line, whereas you could feasibly do so with the `function` example.

As far as the difference between `function(num) {` versus `(num) => {`, well in your example it makes no difference. But there are some differences... for example

```
const thisWillFail = () => {
    console.log(arguments.length);
};
const thisWorks = function() {
    console.log(arguments.length);
};
```

If you're unfamiliar with the `arguments` object, you can find info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).