# Why can you not refer to a variable when shadowing it?

Tags: javascript, scope

Why does block A result in a ReferenceError?

```
const something = 'something';

console.log ();

try {

    // Block A
    {

        const something = something;

    }

} catch (e) { console.log(e); }

console.log ();

// Block B
{

    const something = 'somethingElse';

}
```

This prevents one from shadowing a variable with one of its properties.

Comment: You can just change the name of the outer variable and move on. Unless I am missing something this does not really pose a real-life issue.

Comment: check doc [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block)

Comment: @Thilo It's good to understand how the language works, and I think that's what Stephen is going for here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `const` variables [are hoisted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31219420/1048572), and you are trying to access it in its own temporal dead zone. There are three ways of solving this:

- Just use a different variable name, don't shadow non-global variables. It's confusing.
- Don't use `const`, don't make a local scope - just reassign the variable inside the block. This solution might not be applicable everywhere.
- Use an IIFE:

  ```
  const something = 'something';
  (function(something) {
  //        ^^^^^^^^^ inner scope
      …
  }(something));
  //^^^^^^^^^ outer scope
  ```

Comment: Thanks. I see now what the issue is. From all the JS guides I've read, I got the impression that const and let were spared from hoisting.