# Event listener with arrow functions

Tags: javascript, event-listener

How come the below code is not printing in the console. If I use a normal function it works.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', recipeController);

const recipeController = () => console.log("hello");
```

Comment: @Taplar — The problem doesn't really have anything much to do with arrow functions, and certainly nothing to do with the `this` keyword

Comment: Ah, I misread the question.  Thought it was an arrow function issue, rather than a hoisting issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are variables declared with let or const not hoisted in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219420/are-variables-declared-with-let-or-const-not-hoisted-in-es6)

Answer (score 2):

`const` variables must be declared before they are used. They are not hoisted.

Answer (score 2):

Functions are forward-referencing (hoisted), what you have here is a variable declaration (non-hoisted). In this case, you need to declare your `recipeController` above your event listener.

```js
const recipeController = () => console.log("hello");
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', recipeController);
```