# eslint rule to enforce that variables are declared at the top of the block?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint, ecmascript-2016

Is there an eslint rule to enforce that variables are declared at the top of the block? The `vars-on-top` rule seems to literally only apply to the `var` keyword, and is not what I want (e.g. it would disallow `for (var i = 0; ...)`. Here is a contrived example.

**Bad Code**

```
doWork() {
    const work = this.getWork();

    if (work.isReady) { ... }

    let workResult = work.getResult();

    // ...

    return workResult;
}
```

**Good Code**

```
doWork() {
    const work = this.getWork();
    let workResult;

    if (work.isReady) { ... }

    workResult = work.getResult();

    // ...

    return workResult;
}
```

Comment: Why do you call that good code? Shouldn't `let workResult` be declared before `this.getWork()`?

Comment: `this.getWork()` is not declared in my example, it's only called.

Comment: Yes, I mean it should be declared before anything else is called. `var work, workResult; work = this.getWork(); …`

Answer (score 5):

I'm unaware of a rule for that.

The `var` rule served a pretty important purpose: to prevent you accidentally introducing bugs due to the non-obvious hoisting behavior that `var`s have. The rule forced you to hoist them yourselves, making the behavior obvious (if still someone annoying)

With `let` and `const` [that's no longer an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31219420/1048572), so the main practical reasons for enforcing that behavior aren't around any more. Using a variable before it's defined can still be a problem, but there's a [`no-use-before-define` rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-use-before-define) which handles that (including for `let` and `const`).

Comment: +1. In fact, it might be impossible to manually "hoist" a `const` declaration out of  the control flow - it must be declared where it is initialised.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I understand the reason for the `vars-on-top` rule and how `let`/`const` solve the issue of hoisting. This is more of a code-style issue.

Comment: @JoshM. Var-on-top is a horrible code style that leads to lots of duplication. Declare your variables where you need them :-)

Comment: @Bergi I know it's subjective but if you are declaring variables in the middle of a function, your function probably is too long and should be split out.