# Arrow Functions don't works. Regular ones do. Why?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I have a piece of code, that is just vanilla javascript. When I use arrow functions I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: loadEventListeners is not defined
```

When I use regular function, syntax, it works fine.

Here is my code:

```
const form = document.querySelector('#task-form');
const taskList = document.querySelector('.collection');
const clearBtn = document.querySelector('.clear-tasks');
const filter = document.querySelector('#filter');
const taskInput = document.querySelector('#task');

// Load all event listeners
loadEventListeners();

// Load all event listeners
const loadEventListeners = () => {
  // Add task event
  form.addEventListener('submit', addTask);
}

// Add Task
const addTask = (e) => {
  if(taskInput.value === '') {
    alert('Add a task');
  }

  // Create li element
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  // Add class
  li.className = 'collection-item';
  // Create text node and append to li
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(taskInput.value));
  // Create new link element
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  // Add class
  link.className = 'delete-item secondary-content';
  // Add icon html
  link.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-remove"></i>';
  // Append the link to li
  li.appendChild(link);

  // Append li to ul
  taskList.appendChild(li);

  // Clear input
  taskInput.value = '';

  e.preventDefault();
}
```

My question is this. **Do I need to do something that enables arrow functions, in my code? Maybe I need to setup Webpack or Parcel for this? I do not know why this is. Just replace the `const <functionName> = () => {}` with `function <functionName>() {}` and it works. Would really like a more thorough explanation why this is happening, if it is possible.**

Thanks for your time..

Comment: `const` vars are not available before they’re declared. Move the declaration above the invocation. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219420/are-variables-declared-with-let-or-const-not-hoisted-in-es6

Comment: Also, this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Comment: check out the topic of [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's something called [Temporal Dead Zone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_Dead_Zone)

> `let` bindings are created at the top of the (block) scope containing
>   the declaration, commonly referred to as "hoisting". Unlike variables
>   declared with `var`, which will start with the value **undefined**,
>   `let` variables are not initialized until their definition is
>   evaluated. Accessing the variable before the initialization results in
>   a **ReferenceError**. The variable is in a "temporal dead zone" from
>   the start of the block until the initialization is processed.
>
> All the considerations about the "temporal dead zone" apply to both
>   `let` and `const`.

Example:

```
function do_something() {
  console.log(bar); // undefined
  console.log(foo); // ReferenceError
  var bar = 1;
  let foo = 2;
}
```

---

In your case, just simply define the function first before using it.