# How to change variables in my javascript code

Tags: javascript

I have written javascript code which shows current date, it works wery well. The problem is that, i want to change "var" variable to "let" or "const", but when i change it, itdoesnot work. can you help me? i want modern javascript code.

here is my code

```
  const objToday = new Date(),
  weekday = new Array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'),
  dayOfWeek = weekday[objToday.getDay()],
  domEnder = function() { let a = objToday; if (/1/.test(parseInt((a + "").charAt(0)))) return "th"; a = parseInt((a + "").charAt(1)); return 1 == a ? "st" : 2 == a ? "nd" : 3 == a ? "rd" : "th" }(),
  dayOfMonth = today + ( objToday.getDate() < 10) ? '0' + objToday.getDate() + domEnder : objToday.getDate() + domEnder,
  months = new Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'),
  curMonth = months[objToday.getMonth()],
  curYear = objToday.getFullYear(),
  curHour = objToday.getHours() > 12 ? objToday.getHours() - 12 : (objToday.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + objToday.getHours() : objToday.getHours()),
  curMinute = objToday.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + objToday.getMinutes() : objToday.getMinutes(),
  curSeconds = objToday.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + objToday.getSeconds() : objToday.getSeconds(),
  curMeridiem = objToday.getHours() > 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
  yesterday = (function(d){ d.setDate(d.getDate()-1); return d})(new Date);

  var today =  dayOfWeek;
  var todaysDate = dayOfMonth + " " +curMonth + "," +curYear;
  var currentTime = curHour + ":" + curMinute + curMeridiem;
  var currenTDate = "today is " + dayOfWeek;
  var curMonthDay = curMonth + dayOfMonth;
  var yestDate = "Yesterday was: " + yesterday;


  document.querySelector(".h11").textContent = today;
  document.querySelector(".h12").textContent = todaysDate;
  document.querySelector(".hour").textContent = currentTime;
  document.querySelector(".h40").textContent = currenTDate;
  document.querySelector(".h41").textContent = curMonthDay;
  document.querySelector(".h42").textContent = yestDate;
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Error messages?

Comment: Does it show an error? Perhaps you are testing in the console and the variables are already defined?

Comment: there is an error    "Cannot access 'today' before initialization"

Comment: whe i change the "var" to "const"

Comment: shows that there is a mistake on line 5

Answer (score 1):

When you use `var`, the variable declaration is hoisted and initialized with `undefined`. When you use `const` or `let`, they are hoisted but are not initialized. So when you say line 5 is the problem here, you can see why `today` is throwing an error. Here's a little demo. You'll notice how the `var` example gives `undefined` while the `const` example gives `(index):40 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'const_name' before initialization`.

```js
// With var
var test1 = d1;
console.log(test1);

var d1 =  new Date();


// With const
const test2 = d2;
console.log(test2)

const d2 = new Date();
```

To fix this you can move `const d2 = new Date()` above `const test2 = d2`.

```js
// With var
var test1 = d1;
console.log(test1);

var d1 =  new Date();


// With const
const d2 = new Date();
const test2 = d2;
console.log(test2)
```

For more reading you can check out: [Are variables declared with let or const not hoisted in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219420/are-variables-declared-with-let-or-const-not-hoisted-in-es6)