# Please explain why this code returns undefined

Tags: javascript, function, undefined, hoisting

I assume that function hoisting  will not allow to access parent functions product but why global scope is not accessed.Please Help.Thanks

```js
const product = 'product'

function foo() {
  employeeId();
  var product = 'Car';
  return;

  function employeeId() {
    //this is giving me undefined
    console.log(product);
  }
}

foo();
```

When I try to get the value of product it's giving undefined.
I am very confused, not sure what is causing this issue at all.

Comment: Two things: 1, `product` inside `foo` is not the global `product` (search for *"shadowing"*). 2, the explanation in the upvoted answer still applies.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `employeeId()` before the variable assignment. When javascript run the code it first assign undefined for all variables that are stored in var,let and const. That's why you got undefined. If you call `employeeId()` after the `var product = 'Car'` it will show the correct value

Comment: Only variables declared with `var` get initialized with `undefined` when they are hoisted. `let` and `const` will be in [temporal dead zone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31222689)

Comment: Thanks.But why globally defined const product is not available in inner function.

Answer (score 1):

Because JS is **single threaded** programming language . It means only one set of instructions is executed at a time !

so you need to call `employeeId()` after `var product = 'Car'` and then return it

```
function foo() {
    var product = 'Car'; 
    return employeeId();
    function employeeId() {
         console.log(product);
  }
 }
 foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

The function and variable will be hoisted. But watch out, only the declaration will be hoisted. While the assignment process will be in the next stage. Therefore, you are calling the function to print `product` while it hasn't been initialised. `undefined` will hence be shown.

```
const product = 'product'

function foo() {
  //JS interpret like this for the hoisting effect
  var product;
  employeeId();
  product = 'Car';
  return;

  function employeeId() {
    //actually printing the variable which located inside the function
    console.log(product);
  }
}

foo();
```

Another testing case with different variable names

```
const product2 = 'product'

function foo2() {
  //JS interpret like this for the hoisting effect
  var product;
  employeeId();
  product = 'Car';
  return;

  function employeeId() {
    //print the global variable
    console.log(product2);
  }
}

foo2();
```

Comment: Please clarify how  is your code answering my question.My question is simple why global variable is not accessed by inner function.

Comment: check the revised version.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.But please see my revised code.
If i am not wrong u mean to say that globally defined variable which has same name as declared in function  will not be accessed in any function. Instead of that  local variable will be accessed which is undefined.

Comment: If the function can find the variable with the same name in current scope. It will stop searching. Therefore, In this case, the global variable cannot be accessed. Check out my answer to see how to access global variable.

Answer (score 0):

During the declaration phase, in the inner function, the variables and function get hoisted and your variable `var product` gets declared as soon as the execution engine encounters this and sets its value `undefined`. The variable is assigned a value 'Car' later so at the time `employeeId()` is called, `product`'s value is still `undefined`.

Note that the global `const product = 'product'` has no role to play in this. Even you declare the global product with `let` or `var`, the result will be the same. During the initialisation phase, var product will again be declared in the inner function and its value will be set to `undefined`

```js
var product = 'product' //Even if you declare this with let/const the result will be same

function foo() {
  employeeId();
  var product = 'Car';
  return;

  function employeeId() {
    //this is giving me undefined
    console.log(product);
  }
}

foo();
```