# variable hoisting in browser console problem

Tags: javascript

(1) why are the two examples different?

```js
console.log(a); 
a = 1; // this will have a is not defined;
```

```js
console.log(a); 
function a(){}; // this will have no error;
```

(2)In browser console.

```
console.log(a); 
a = 1; 
window.a === 1; // true
```

why is the variable `a` bound to `window` but `console.log` still has an error.

```
window.a = 1;
console.log(a);
```

why is the variable `a` bound to `window` but `console.log` has no error.

Comment: This isn't limited to the console - that's how normal JavaScript works

Comment: Of all your examples, only the second one with `function a() {}` has hoisting. None of the other examples employ variable hoisting because [they don't have variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-should-i-use-it-or-omit-it) which is exactly why you get a problem. Without hoisting you cannot access an identifier before it's declared.

Comment: `function` declarations are hoisted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the first example `console.log(a); a = 1;` will return an error because your variable is not declared and only declared variables are hoisted using a keyword such as `var` for example

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

> JavaScript only hoists declarations, not initializations. If a
> variable is declared and initialized after using it, the value will be
> undefined.

The ex `console.log(a); function a(){};` doesn't return an error
because JavaScript is adding the function declarations to memory before it executes aka [Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

in the example `console.log(a); a = 1; window.a === 1;` will return an error because your variable is not declared, *same as the first example*

in this example `window.a = 1; console.log(a)`won't return an error because you added the variable to the global object `window` and gave it a value of 1 before attempting to print it's value.

Comment: in the last example. window.a = 1; console.log(a).a will find value from window.a. why console.log(a); a = 1; the console will not find a from window while the window.a is undefined, so the result is undefined not an error.

Comment: @JackieWillen if your run  console.log(a); a = 1 you get this message "Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined" it's an error basically telling you a is not defined

Comment: `console.log(a); a = 1` will return an error because a is initialized but not declared and only declared variables using a keyword such as `var` for example will be hoisted does that makes since ?

Comment: Problem is on console.log(a);   'a' get it's value from window. When window.a=1 console.log(a) will return '1'.Why console.log(a) will not print 'undefined' while window.a  is  indeed 'undefined'

Comment: because `console.log(a); a = 1` you are trying to print the value before JS gives it a reference in memory  (_before JS knows about it's value from memory_)  and  `window.a = 1; console.log(a)` you first told JS the value of `a` and then you print the value (_JS will be able to print the value of a and not undefined because he has reference to the variable a with value 1 in memory_)

Comment: Thank you.But console.log(window.a); a=1; will print 'undefined' While console.log(a); a=1; will print error. They are not same?

Comment: No they are not the same because the global variable `window` exist already and what you are doing by console(window.a) you are telling JS in plain english _go to `window` object and check for variable `a` if it's there and print it in console_  and since there is no variable `a` in window it returns `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

This is called `hoisting` in javascript.

## (1)

```
console.log(a); 
a = 1; // this will have a is not defined;
```

In the above snippet, a is assigned after `console`, so it is throwing an error.

In case if you have

```
 console.log(a);
 var a = 1;
```

The result will be `undefined` printed in the console. It is because of hoisting. Javascript will execute the above in the following order.

```
var a;
console.log(a);
a = 1;
```

**Hoisting** is executing the initialisation first and rest of the execution will go as per the flow.

`var a;` is executed first and `a` is initialized to the scope. Hence `console.log(a)` will not throw any error. At the time of its execution, `a` value is `undefined`.

## (2)

```
console.log(a); 
a = 1; 
window.a === 1; // true
```

Whenever you try to do anything in the console, all the variables and functions will be registered with the `window` scope. So, when you do `a = 1` in console, it will be `window.a`.

## (3)

```
console.log(a); 
function a(){}; // this will have no error;
```

The same `hoisting` applies to functions also. When you created a function using constructor like above, it will be `hoisted`. If you execute the below snippet you will get error because it is not `hoisted`.

```
console.log(a)
a = function(){}
```

> **why is the variable a bound to window but console.log still has an error.**

The variable is registered with `window` scope, but it is not hoisted. So you will get error. `Hoisting` will only work when you initialize a variable.

To get further details about `hoisting`, feel free to read [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

Comment: "*In the above snippet, a is declared after console*" it's **not** declared, it's only assigned. Implicit assignment to global objects are not counted as declarations.

Comment: "*If you do the below snippet you will get error as it is not hoisted.*" [`let` and `const` variables **are** hoisted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219420/are-variables-declared-with-let-or-const-hoisted) however you're running into the temporal dead zone. TDZ can *only* exist if the declaration is hoisted, so the environment will know that the binding is "reserved" but not usable *yet*, hence you'd get a different error than just the identifier being *unusable* (e.g., trying to read an undeclared variable)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> console.log(a);  a = 1; // this will have a is not defined;
> console.log(a);  function a(){}; // this will have no error;
> ```

The `function` keyword is bound before any code will be excuted in JS.

> ```
> console.log(a); 
> a = 1; 
> window.a === 1; // true
> ```
>
> why is the variable a bound to window but console.log still has an
> error.
>
> ```
> window.a = 1;
> console.log(a);
> ```
>
> why is the variable a bound to window but console.log has no error.

You're already in the window context. So `a` is the same as `window.a`.