# JS - How to add dynamic objects to array [code]

Tags: javascript

```js
const feature = [
    {
      attributes: {
        data: {
          rootType: { type: "string", value: "Alpha" },
          rootAge: { type: "integer", value: "10" },
          baySize: { type: "integer", value: "18" },
          totalBays: { type: "integer", value: "13" }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      attributes: {
        data: {
          rootType: { type: "string", value: "Brown" },
          rootAge: { type: "integer", value: "20" },
          baySize: { type: "integer", value: "180" },
          totalBays: { type: "integer", value: "30" }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      attributes: {
        data: {
          rootType: { type: "string", value: "Alpha" },
          rootAge: { type: "integer", value: "50" },
          baySize: { type: "integer", value: "80" },
          totalBays: { type: "integer", value: "25" }
        }
      }
    }
  ];
  const allData = feature.map((item) => {
    const { data } = item.attributes;
    return data
  });
console.log(allData);
```

```js
const expectedResult = [
  {
    rootType: { type: "string", value: "Alpha" },
    rootAge: { type: "integer", value: "10" },
    baySize: { type: "integer", value: "18" },
    totalBays: { type: "integer", value: "13" }
  },
  {
    rootType: { type: "string", value: "Brown" },
    rootAge: { type: "integer", value: "20" },
    baySize: { type: "integer", value: "180" },
    totalBays: { type: "integer", value: "30" }
  },
  {
    rootType: { type: "string", value: "Alpha" },
    rootAge: { type: "integer", value: "50" },
    baySize: { type: "integer", value: "80" },
    totalBays: { type: "integer", value: "25" }
  }
]

console.log(expectedResult)
```

I have array of object which I get from API.

[image]

I need a way to add these objects into array as below.

[image]

I have tried mapping over the original array and push these objects to new variable but I can only ever get the first one.

what is the best way to achieve the desired result.

looking forward to your response. thanks

Comment: The expected result seems like the data you get. What is the difference?

Comment: @VLAZ I think he has just shown what he wants it to look like. Can you please share the code that you have tried?

Comment: simple push your reponse in an array

Comment: @VLAZ, have update the code,

Comment: @Phobos, you are right. I have updated the code.

Comment: Your only issue with your map() is you didn't `return data` so you end up with array `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`

Comment: @ChauGiang have updated the code, sorry question wasn't well written but simple push would work if objects were assigned to some variable.

Comment: Now that you added the return.... using map() is best tool for the task

Comment: Hey Guys, I see what I was doing wrong. have fixed it. thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 0):

This script will push each object into the created array.
You could create the expected Array first. You should Push it right after you create the array.

```
var expectedResult = [];

const dataOne = {
        rootType: { type: "string", value: "Alpha" },
        rootAge: { type: "integer", value: "10" },
        baySize: { type: "integer", value: "18" },
        totalBays: { type: "integer", value: "13" }
      };
expectedResult.push(dataOne);
      const dataTwo = {
        rootType: { type: "string", value: "Brown" },
        rootAge: { type: "integer", value: "20" },
        baySize: { type: "integer", value: "180" },
        totalBays: { type: "integer", value: "30" }
      };
expectedResult.push(dataTwo);
      const dataThree = {
        rootType: { type: "string", value: "Alpha" },
        rootAge: { type: "integer", value: "50" },
        baySize: { type: "integer", value: "80" },
        totalBays: { type: "integer", value: "25" }
      };

expectedResult.push(dataThree);
```

Comment: Just an opinion but the whole section on `const` is just noise unrelated to OP's problem

Comment: I don't really get why half the answer is about `const` and even then some of the bullet point are...odd, to say the least: "*Primitive value.*" ??? "*Cannot be Hoisted.*" [it *is* hoisted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219420/are-variables-declared-with-let-or-const-hoisted)