# jest ReferenceError: Cannot access '' before initialization

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm getting the error:

`ReferenceError: Cannot access 'myMock' before initialization`

Even though i respected jest documentation about the hoisting:
[`A limitation with the factory parameter is that, since calls to jest.mock() are hoisted to the top of the file, it's not possible to first define a variable and then use it in the factory. An exception is made for variables that start with the word 'mock'.`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmockdocsenjest-objectjestmockmodulename-factory-options-with-the-module-factory-parameter)

I'm doing this:

```js
import MyClass from './my_class';
import * as anotherClass from './another_class';

const mockMethod1 = jest.fn();
const mockMethod2 = jest.fn();
jest.mock('./my_class', () => {
  return {
    default: {
      staticMethod: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(
        {
          method1: mockMethod1,
          method2: mockMethod2,
        })
    }
  }
});
```

as you can see both of my variables respect the "standard" but are not hoisted properly.

Am I missing something ?

Obviously it works when I just pass `jest.fn()` instead of my variables, but i'm not sure how to be able to use these in my test later on.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The accepted answer does not handle when you need to spy on the `const` declaration, as it is defined inside the module factory scope.

For me, the module factory needs to be **above** any import statement that *eventually* imports the thing you want to mock.
Here is a code snippet using a [nestjs](https://docs.nestjs.com/) with [prisma](https://www.prisma.io/) library.

```
// app.e2e.spec.ts
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as request from 'supertest';
import mockPrismaClient from './utils/mockPrismaClient'; // you can assert, spy, etc. on this object in your test suites.

// must define this above the `AppModule` import, otherwise the ReferenceError is raised.
jest.mock('@prisma/client', () => {
  return {
    PrismaClient: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => mockPrismaClient),
  };
});

import { AppModule } from './../src/app.module'; // somwhere here, the prisma is imported

describe('AppController (e2e)', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });
)};
```

Comment: Actually, this is not a correct way to address the problem. It's technically wrong to put anything above imports and expect that it will be evaluated in this order, because ESM imports are hoisted by specs, and jest.mock is hoisted by Jest via Babel transform, this is also specified. It may work in one setup and fail in another because the behaviour is undetermined. A correct way to use mockPrismaClient in a mock is to import it with `require` or `jest.requireActual` inside `jest.mock` instead of relying on a value from parent scope.

Comment: So far, this method has always worked for me for a variety of setups. However, I've never known if there is a "technically right way to do it". Mind sharing a piece of code example to what you just explained?

Comment: I meant basically it's `import mpc from './utils/mockPrismaClient'; jest.mock('@prisma/client', () => { const mpc = require('./utils/mockPrismaClient').default; return { PrismaClient: jest.fn(() => mpc) } ));`. So mock's dependency on utility module is explicitly specified and isn't tied to potential race conditions. Also this allows it to be extracted to `__mocks__` if needed.

Answer (score 73):

None of the answers above solved my problem, so here's my solution:

```js
const mockMyMethod = jest.fn();

jest.mock('some-package', () => ({
  myMethod: () => mockMyMethod()
}));
```

EDIT

The previous solution used hoisting the `var`, but that's a weird work-around. The updated solution does so without hoisting in a way that jest is happy with. It works because the `mockMyMethod` function is not actually executed until the `myMethod` method is called from the mocked package.

Comment: I was trying using `let` outside of the `jest.mock` to assign it internally and it was failing. Using `var` solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: This is because: 1) [Jest hoists](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#using-with-es-module-imports) `jest.mock()` calls. 2) [Jest does not hoist](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/1088#issuecomment-562975615) variables that begin with  `mock`. 3) Variables declared with `var` [are always hoisted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11444416) in JavaScript, whereas variables declared with `let` and `const` are not.

Comment: I tried it but failed to work with error "TypeError: mockMyMethod is not a function"

Comment: @Orionpax you should be able to use `mockMyMethod` if you define it as a function!

Comment: There is just small mistake replace `:` with `=` in `const mockMyMethod: jest.fn();` . I know it's not done intentionally. Thanks.

Comment: @JaiPrak I've adjusted, thank you

Answer (score 25):

To clarify what [Jason Limantoro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67114668/481207) said, move the `const` above where the module is imported:

```
const mockMethod1 = jest.fn(); // Defined here before import.
const mockMethod2 = jest.fn();

import MyClass from './my_class'; // Imported here.
import * as anotherClass from './another_class';

jest.mock('./my_class', () => {
  return {
    default: {
      staticMethod: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(
        {
          method1: mockMethod1,
          method2: mockMethod2,
        })
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This helped fix my issue. It is the clearest answer as well.

Answer (score 16):

**You should move your mocking above your imports**; that could be the source of your issue. [Imports are also hoisted](https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_imports-are-hoisted), so multiple hoisted entries would be hoisted in order.

```js
jest.mock('./my_class', () => {
  const mockMethod = jest.fn() 
  const default = { staticMethod: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ method: mockMethod }) };
  return { default, mockMethod };
});

import MyClass, { mockMethod } from './my_class';  // will import your mock
import * as anotherClass from './another_class';
```

However, if you for some reason can't do that, **you could use [`doMock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options) to avoid hoisting behaviour**. If this happens on the top of your file, it should be a 1 to 1 change.

```js
var mockMyMethod = jest.fn();
jest.doMock('some-package', () => ({ myMethod: mockMyMethod }));
```

I also recommend using `var` instead of `const` or `let` for mocks. [Their hoisting behaviour is slightly different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31222689/36272), and I've found a few times that using `var` seems to work better with jest's own hoisting.

Comment: doMock is the answer - thank you

Answer (score 11):

The problem that the documentation addresses is that `jest.mock` is hoisted but `const` declaration is not. This results in factory function being evaluated at the time when mocked module is imported and a variable being in temporal dead zone.

If it's necessary to access nested mocked functions, they need to be exposed as a part of export object:

```
jest.mock('./my_class', () => {
  const mockMethod1 = jest.fn();
  const mockMethod2 = jest.fn();
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    mockMethod1,
    mockMethod2,
    default: {
      ...
```

This also applies to manual mocks in `__mocks__` where variables are accessible inside a mock only.

Comment: mmmh yet the documentation state that there is an exception for variable starting with the word "mock". Thats strange !
I'll give your solution a try thanks !

Comment: you sir are a savior ! it works like a charm !

Comment: ok, i guess i misunderstood the doc stating that there was an exception then

Comment: @EstusFlask I'm definitely reading it the same way Sufiane is. Take a look at the example here: https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-with-the-module-factory-parameter

They are doing almost the exact same thing the original asker is trying to do.

Comment: @Sam They could do a better job at explaining the case they warn about. The obvious difference is that the documentation doesn't have `anotherClass` that does side effects on import.

Comment: I've found that using `var` instead of `const` sometimes helps, allowing the variables that start with `mock` to work properly.

Answer (score 7):

I got in the same problem.

> ReferenceError: Cannot access 'mockYourFunction' before initialization

The selected answer works, but the explanation is wrong, **it is not because the import order**.
The reason it works is because the answer changed `mockResturnValue` to `mockImplementation`.

`mockResturnValue` will try to resolve the value immediately while
`mockImplementation` will do it only when been invoked, given the time needed to your variable be there when needed.

some, to exemplify a working solution, without reorder imports or add var and avoiding some fervent comments in your PR, here is the important part of the code:

```js
const mockPrismaClient = jest.fn();
jest.mock('@prisma/client', () => {
  return {
    PrismaClient: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => mockPrismaClient),
  };
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Per [this article](https://www.bam.tech/article/fix-jest-mock-cannot-access-before-initialization-error)... Anyone making it to this page may just be able to set the mocked function to a function returning a function call. As per the OP's code:

```js
import MyClass from './my_class';
import * as anotherClass from './another_class';

const mockMethod1 = jest.fn();
const mockMethod2 = jest.fn();
jest.mock('./my_class', () => {
  return {
    default: {
      staticMethod: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(
        {
          method1: () => mockMethod1(), // <- function returning function call
          method2: () => mockMethod2(),
        })
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers helped. Trying to use var kept giving me the TypeError: mockMyMethod is not a function. Yes I tried several function styles (delegate, function, etc).

What worked for me (disclaimer, this might not work with 3rd party packages, it might only work with your custom packages) :

```js
import * as somePackage from 'some-package';
...

describe('desc', () => {
  ...
  beforeEach(() => {
    var mockMyMethod: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({myMethod: whateverHere, etc: null});
    jest.spyOn(somePackage, 'methodOrHookName').mockImplementation(mockMyMethod);
  });
  
  it(...)
  
  it('testWithDifferentValue', () => {
    var mockMyMethod: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({myMethod: superDifferent, etc: 'etc'});
    jest.spyOn(somePackage, 'methodOrHookName').mockImplementation(mockMyMethod);    
    // write test that is different to other tests.
    
  });
}));
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, it turns out the issue was from a typing error I had, so check your types :)

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that it is because of how I was passing the mocked implementation. Here is how I was doing it:

## Wrong code:

```
import { BaseQueryApi } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query';
import { waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import axios from 'axios';

const mockWaitForUnlock = jest.fn();
const axiosMock = jest.mocked(axios);

jest.mock('axios');
jest.mock('async-mutex', () => ({
    // Or: Mutex: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    Mutex: jest.fn(() => ({
        waitForUnlock: mockWaitForUnlock,
    })),
}));
```

## Working solution

```
import { BaseQueryApi } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query';
import { waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import axios from 'axios';

const mockWaitForUnlock = jest.fn();
const axiosMock = jest.mocked(axios);

jest.mock('axios');
jest.mock('async-mutex', () => ({
    Mutex: jest.fn(() => ({
        waitForUnlock: jest
            .fn()
            .mockImplementation(() => mockWaitForUnlock),
    })),
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me and it's pretty easy for vuejs+ jest.

Two points to note:

- you should declare the absolute path and not '@/js/network/repositories'
- the getter helps to defer the instantiation

```js
    const mockGetNextStatuses = jest.fn();
    const mockUpdatePrintingStatus = jest.fn();
    
    jest.mock('../../../../../../src/js/network/repositories/index.js', () => {
        return {
            get printing() {
                return {
                    getNextStatuses: mockGetNextStatuses,
                    updatePrintingStatus: mockUpdatePrintingStatus,
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

or

```js
jest.mock('../../../../../../src/js/network/repositories/index.js', () => ({
    printing: {
        getNextStatuses: jest.fn(),
        updatePrintingStatus: jest.fn()
    }
}));
import { printing } from '../../../../../../src/js/network/repositories/index.js';


// and mock the module
printing.getNextStatuses.mockReturnValue(['XX','YY']);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

```js
jest.mock("../user/useCases/GetUserBalancesUseCase.js", () => {
  return {
    GetUserBalancesUseCase: {
      create: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
        execute: jest
          .fn()
          .mockReturnValue(require("./fixtures/user/useCaseResponse.js").useCaseResponse),
      }),
    },
  }
})
```

I couldn't use the fixture importing it using ESM syntax in this implementation. So I tried using *require* and fixed the import reference error issue.

This kind of mocking though, is not reliable because bypasses some logic that I want to have covered by the unit test. In my case is necessary to avoid interacting with the infrastructure.

As a reference, I need to test the output of an useCase given an input:

```js
test("Get User Balances", async () => {
    const useCaseResponse = await getUserBalancesUseCase.execute({ account, USDPrices })
    expect(useCaseResponse).toEqual(getUserBalancesUseCaseResponse)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Jest mock method accepts a factory function in the second argument.
so we have a hook named useMessage like this:

```
// hook file
const useMessage = () => {
  return {
    message: 'hi from useMessage hook'
  }
}
```

Now in the code below, we are mocking our hook by returning a new hook made by jest.fn ( you can also do it without jest.fn )

```
// test file
jest.mock(`./useMessage`, () => {
  return jest.fn(() => ({
    message: 'hi from mocked useMessage',
  }))
})
```

Answer (score -2):

Example of using TypeScript with Jest and mockDebug.js module

```js
jest.mock('debug', () => {
  global.mockDebug = jest.fn();
  return () => global.mockDebug;
});

// usage
describe('xxx', () => {
    test('xxx', () => {
        expect(global.mockDebug.mock.calls.toString()).toContain('ccc');
    })
});
```

Comment: What does this mean? Can you elaborate a bit?