# JavaScript arrow function not working with the addEventListener but is working with normal functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

```
const menuBtn = document.querySelector(".menu-btn");
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".menu-btn__burger");

let showMenu = false;

menuBtn.addEventListener("click", toggleMenu);
```

Here, when I am defining **toggleMenu** as an arrow function -

```
const toggleMenu = () => {
  if (!showMenu) {
    hamburger.classList.add("open");
    showMenu = true;
  } else {
    hamburger.classList.remove("open");
    showMenu = false;
  }
};
```

then in the console I am getting an error as -

> main.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'toggleMenu' before
> initialization
> at main.js:6

But, when I am defining the **toggleMenu** as a normal JavaScript function -

```
function toggleMenu() {
  console.log("Clicked");
  if (!showMenu) {
    hamburger.classList.add("open");
    showMenu = true;
  } else {
    hamburger.classList.remove("open");
    showMenu = false;
  }
}
```

then it is working perfectly fine without any error.

Why is it so?

Comment: You just need to move the function definition to the top of the code, before you call it.

Comment: This is because of "hoisting". Normally, variables can only be used after they are declared, but functions work as if they were placed in the beginning of the current scope (the current function or file, for example)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219420/are-variables-declared-with-let-or-const-hoisted