# Why can't assignment be done before the variable declaration with let and const?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

I've read on multiple websites (like w3schools) that hoisting is "the behavior of moving all declarations to the top of the current scope".

For `let` and `const`, the variables are hoisted but not initialized.

I understand why the following code does not work as `name` has no value for us to access.

```js
console.log(name);
let name = "hi";
```

But why can't we assign a value to `name` before its actual declaration, even though `name` has been declared (hoisting)?

```js
name = "hi";
let name;
console.log(name);
```

Isn't the above code the same as the following,

```js
let name;
name = "hi";
console.log(name);
```

Comment: Also see [Are variables declared with let or const hoisted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219420/are-variables-declared-with-let-or-const-hoisted)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because they're explicitly designed not to allow that, because it's usually a programming mistake.

`let` and `const` *are* hoisted, but it's just the declaration of the binding that's hoisted. (Loosely, "binding" means "variable" [or constant or parameter...things with names we use to hold values].) The binding is not *initialized* until later, when the `let` or `const` statement is reached in the step-by-step execution of the code. You can't use an uninitialized binding (in any way), which is why you get an error.

In contrast, with `var` both declaration *and* initialization are hoisted; `var` bindings are initialized with the value `undefined`. If there's an initialization value on the `var` (`var a = 42`), later when the `var` statement is reached in the step-by-step execution of the code, that part is treated as simple assignment (`a = 42`). With `let` and `const`, it's not just simple assignment, it's initialization of the binding, allowing it to be used.

Here's a concrete example of how `let` hoists the declaration but not the initialization, and why it helps prevent programming mistakes:

```js
let a = 1;

function foo() {
    a = 2;  // <=== Which `a` should be assigned to?
    console.log(a);
    
    // code
    // code
    // code
    // code
    // code
    // code
    // code
    // code

    let a = 3;
    console.log(a);
}

foo();
```

In that code, it seems like the assignment at the top of `foo` should assign to the outer `a`, since (as far as we know reading top-down) there's no other `a` in scope. But there is, because the `let` at the bottom of `foo` is hoisted. You get an error doing the assignment because that inner `a` isn't initialized.

In contrast, with `var`, there's no error but it's easy to be confused about which `a` was assigned at the top of `foo`.

---

In comments you've indicated you're still not understanding what it means for a binding to be declared but not initialized. I think the two (slightly) meanings of "initialization"¹ are confusing you here (they confused me when I got into this stuff), so let's change terminology slightly.

Bindings have a flag associated with them saying whether they can be used or not. Let's call it the `usable` flag: `usable = true` means the binding can be used, `usable = false` means it can't. Using that terminology, the example above is handled like this:

1. When the execution context for the script is created:

   1. Bindings for all top level declarations within it are created:

      - The `let a` part of `let a = 1;` creates a binding called `a` with its `usable` flag set to `false` (can't be used yet).
      - The function declaration (`function foo() { }`) creates a binding called `foo` with its `usable` flag set to `true` (can b eused) and its value set to `undefined`.
   2. Function declarations within the context are processed by creating the functions they define and assigning them to the binding. So `foo` gets its function value.
2. When the `let a = 1;` statement is encountered in the step-by-step execution of the code, it does two things: It sets the `usable` flag to `true` (can be used) and sets the value of `a` to `1`.
3. When `foo` is called and the execution context for the call is created, bindings for top-level declarations are created:

   1. A binding called `a` is created by `let a = 3;` with its `usable` flag set to `false` (can't be used yet).
4. When the `a = 2;` statement is reached in the step-by-step execution of the code, the `a` resolves to the inner `a` binding (the one in `foo`, declared by `let a = 3;`), but that binding's `usable` flag is `false`, so trying to use it throws an error.
5. ***If*** we didn't have the `a = 2;` statement, so no error was thrown, then when the step-by-step code execution reached the `let a = 3;` statement, it would do two things: Sets the `usable` flag to `true` (can be used) and set the value of `a` to `3`.

Here's `foo` updated with some comments:

```
function foo() {
    // The local `a` is created but marked `usable` = `false`

    a = 2;      // <=== Throws error because `a`'s `usable` is `false`
    console.log(a);
    
    let a = 3;  // <=== If there weren't an error above, this would set
                //      `usable` to `true` and the value of `a` to `3`
    console.log(a);
}
```

---

¹ *"I think the two (slightly) meanings of "initialization"¹ are confusing you here..."* The two meanings I'm referring to are:

1. "Initializing" the binding (making it usable, setting `usable` to `true`), and separately
2. "Initializing" as in setting the initial value of a binding.

They are separate things.

Comment: Ok. Any good resource to read this up?

Comment: @TusharShahi - At the risk of self-promotion, Chapter 2 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys* covers this in detail; links [here](https://thenewtoys.dev). ;-)

Comment: If the declaration of ```let a = 3``` is hoisted to the top the of the function, 
why doesn't the program just output 2 followed by 3?

Comment: @NewbieToCoding - Because, as I said in the answer, the *initialization* of the binding is not hoisted, and you can't use an uninitialized binding.

Comment: But how is ```let a; a = 3;``` different from ```a = 3; let a;``` if in the second case, the declaration is hoisted such that it becomes the same as the first code?

Why does the second code produce an error?

Comment: @NewbieToCoding - I think the two meanings of "initialization" are confusing you here (they certainly confused me when I first got into this). I've added to the end of the answer to try to explain it further with a slight change in terminology.

Comment: *The function declaration (function foo() { }) creates a binding called foo with its usable flag set to true (can be used) and its value set to undefined.* But it is not undefined right? foo is not undefined and can be called. Please correct me

Comment: @TusharShahi - See step 1.2 in that list. :-) (The spec does it in the way shown above, but it's impossible to see the `undefined` value of `foo` between step 1.1 and 1.2 so it's absolutely fine to think of it has the binding is created with the function as its initial value. I wanted to be true to the spec in the list, but pragmatically it's as though the binding were created with the function value to start with.)