# How can variable be used in promise chaining before declaration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise

I came across the following code while working with promises. And it works correctly.

I have read shallowly on how async/await code is run on node. But, in the following code, how is the `session` variable accessible inside the `.then()` function? Is it just by sheer chance that this code works or is there something about how node runs async/await code that makes the `session` variable available inside the `.then()` function?

```js
async function asyncFunction(
  cb: (filePath: string, session: Session) => Promise<any>,
) {
    readFile().then(filePath => cb(filePath, session));
    const session = await verifyToken();
}
```

Comment: That's typescript, `session` is the definition of a parameter, not a variable.

Comment: I copied this code from my typescript project, that is why it has the type hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it just by sheer chance that this code works?

Yes. If `verifyToken` takes longer than `readFile`, `session` will [not be initialised](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31219420/1048572) when the `.then()` callback runs and you'll get an exception.

The proper solution for this problem is `Promise.all`, and not using a callback:

```
async function asyncFunction(): Promise<[filePath: string, session: Session]> {
    return Promise.all([readFile(), verifyToken()]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect example of variable scope. In your case this is a sheer chance that this code works. Since the `readFile` takes longer than `verifyToken`. As a result, the `session` variable is initiated before getting callback in `then` function.

In case the `verifyToken` takes longer that `readFile` (even just by a milli-second), then it would throw `Cannot access variable before initialization` Error.