# How to access one object in another object

Tags: javascript, object

I am busy creating an object. The end goal is that each evolution will link to a creature in another object.

```js
let fresh = {
  botamon: {
    name: "Botamon",
    image: new URL("https://www.grindosaur.com/img/games/digimon-world/digimon/12-botamon.jpg"),
    stage: "Fresh",
    type: "Data"
  },
}

let inTraining = {
  koromon: {
    name: "Koromon",
    image: new URL("https://www.grindosaur.com/img/games/digimon-world/digimon/50-koromon.jpg"),
    stage: "In-Training",
    type: "Data",
    preDigivolution: fresh.botamon,
    line: rookie.agumon
  },
}

let rookie = {
  agumon: {
    name: "Agumon",
    Image: new URL("https://www.grindosaur.com/img/games/digimon-world/digimon/1-agumon.jpg"),
    Stage: "Rookie",
    Type: "Vaccine",
    PreDigivolution: inTraining.koromon
  },
}
```

The `line: rookie.agumon` throws an error, because the way this works is that `koromon` evolves to `agumon` so I have no idea why its throwing an error, the error is

`digimon-digivolution.js:41 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'rookie' before initialization`

is it incorrect to call rookie.agumon in the koromon object?

Comment: You cannot access an object before it's created. The line `rookie.agumon` is before the object `rookie` is there. You're trying to put the fish in the frying pan before you've acquired any fish. So, yes - it is incorrect to try and break the linear time flow by trying to use something that will only exist in the future.

Comment: You can use a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) to grab the value from the associated value at the time of accessing the property. Otherwise, you can declare your objects and then update them after they've been declared.

Comment: Related: [Self-references in object literals / initializers](/q/4616202/4642212). There are a few solutions to this, but the one that makes the most sense is to just do separate assignments after all objects are initialized.

Comment: For your use case, it might also make sense to just declare a property with the *name* (as a string) of the other creature, then look that up on the respective level object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to *resolve* an identifier *before its declaration.* The variable is said to be in a [TDZ (temporal dead-zone)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31222689/13561410).

Trying to swap the declaration/initialization statements would still result in a similar `ReferenceError`: The identifier's resolution would still happen in its TDZ. With just the two statements it is impossible to create a [circular reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference).

Instead, you can separate the initializations into individual statements as [@SebastianSimon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4642212/sebastian-simon) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74589162/13561410#comment131661228_74589162), where you assign the references afterwards. Example:

```js
// Initialize separately
const koromon = {/*...*/};
const agumon = {/*...*/};

// Then assign to each other
koromon.digivolution = agumon;
agumon.preDigivolution = koromon;
```

Or you can use [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) to avoid the problem of the TDZ, as [@NickParsons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5648954/nick-parsons) [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74589162/13561410#comment131661206_74589162). This works because *only upon access* are we resolving the identifier, at which time we have already left its TDZ. Example:

```js
const koromon = {
  name: "Koromon",
  get digivolution() { return agumon; }
};
const agumon = {
  name: "Agumon",
  get preDigivolution() { return koromon; }
};

console.log("Koromon's digivolution is:", koromon.digivolution.name);
```

Comment: Appreciated the link for TDZ. That was a great explanation.