# Javascript compiler error in Chrome's console

Tags: javascript, constants, let, angularjs-compile

I was doing some **javascript** coding in **chrome's console**.

When I do:

```
console.log(x);
let x;
```

It gives **"ReferenceError: x is not defined"**

But when I run the below code:

```
let x;
console.log(x);
```

It consoles **"undefined".**

Q1: Why is it happening?

Q2: When I ran the first code in an online js compiler called OneCompiler, it didn't give the same Reference error but gave **"Reference error : cannot access x before initialization"**. Why did the two compilers gave different errors?

Comment: The browser console is not a compiler. The firsst snippet tries to access a variable which isn't known yet. The second code accesses a known variable which doesn't have a value yet

Comment: [Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

Comment: Could you give a link to the OneCompiler snippet you are talking about? I tried both the ["Javascript"](https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3zm3nw54m) and ["NodeJS"](https://onecompiler.com/nodejs/3zm3nwjra) options, and they lead to the same `ReferenceError`.

Comment: @InSync I tried the code in this: https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3zm4uhwew

Yes, they give the same reference error but the message is different, in chrome it says "x is not defined", but in OneCompiler it says "Cannot access 'x' before initialization"

Comment: @derpirscher when I run both snippets with var keywords, it shows undefined in both cases. But, when using let, in both cases I should have got undefined. Please elaborate your comment, I guess Under both sircumstances the let variable should be known.

Comment: @Akrit Chrome's REPL works a bit different; it seems to run each statement separately. If you were to use Firefox's, you would have seen [(nearly) the same message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XA48t.png). More information on MDN: [`x` is not defined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_defined), [Cannot access `x` before initialization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_access_lexical_declaration_before_init).

Comment: Or, you can also wrap those two statements inside a IIFE or a block. The result would then [have no differences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfBFR.png).

Answer (score 0):

In your first code, you call the `console.log(x)` before the `x` even exists, because you define it first after the `console.log(x)`. so there is no reference to an `x`.

In your second code, you define the `x` and then call the `console.log(x)` so your `x` already exists and you get no error. But You have not assigned any value to your `x`. so x has the value "`undefined`". It is always like that in javascript. If you declare a variable without initializing it, the variable has the value "`undefined`"

I hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

This is because of the concept of variable hoisting in javascript. In this code

```
console.log(x);
let x;
```

the variable x gets "hoisted" to the top and since you havent declared a value to it you get the error `ReferenceError: x is not defined`.

In the second code snippet, your approach is correct but since you have not defined *x* therefore you get *undefined*.

Regarding your second question, it is possible that OneCompiler is using a different Javascript engine/implementation hence the difference in error but the underlying cause of the error is the same.

Comment: This is incorrect. The first `x` is referenced in the [temporal dead zone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#temporal_dead_zone_tdz) and is therefore leading to an error. Variables declared with `let` (as with `const` and `class`) are not hoisted at all. Also, the second snippet has no error.

Comment: @InSync in the second snippet why the let variable is not in the temporal dead zone? Please elaborate. I mean we didn't assign any value to them in both snippets, so they should remain in temporal dead zone in both cases and should have shown the same error. Please let me know why this is not the case.

Comment: Fixed the undefined error part, that was a typo. Regarding your statement that  "*Variables declared with let (as with const and class) are not hoisted at all*", is incorrect. A simple google search would have sufficed. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219420/are-variables-declared-with-let-or-const-hoisted and https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-let-and-const-hoisting/

Comment: @Hassoo It depends on what you define "*[hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)*". The word is not defined by the spec, which means one may interpret it as will; I personally consider ES6 declarations to not be hoisted.

Comment: Sorry if that caused some confusion, but I hope that you do get the gist.